# React Native: Getting the position of an element

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native

I am styling an `Image` component with flexbox to be in the center of the screen which works pretty well. Now I want a second `Image` component to be displayed directly on the top of the first one. The second image is using absolute positioning. Currently I'm just guessing pixels so that it fits, but of course this is not accurate and way too much maintainability effort.

I am pretty much looking for the React Native equivalent of jQuery's `.offset()`. Is there such a thing and if there isn't what's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 132):

React Native provides a [`.measure(...)`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#measurecallback) method which takes a callback and calls it with the offsets and width/height of a component:

```
myComponent.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {

    console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
    console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
    console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
    console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
    console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
    console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)
})
```

### Example...

The following calculates the layout of a custom component after it is rendered:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <View ref={view => { this.myComponent = view; }} />
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        // Print component dimensions to console
        this.myComponent.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
            console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
            console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
            console.log('X offset to frame: ' + fx)
            console.log('Y offset to frame: ' + fy)
            console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
            console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)
        })        
    }
}
```

---

### Bug notes

- Note that sometimes the component does not finish rendering before `componentDidMount()` is called. If you are getting zeros as a result from `measure(...)`, then wrapping it in a `setTimeout` should solve the problem, i.e.:

  ```
  setTimeout( myComponent.measure(...), 0 )
  ```

Comment: This way of invocation of `measure` didn't work for me. Had to pass element handle: `const handle = findNodeHandle(this.refs.dropdown); UIManager.measure(handle, (x, y, ...) ...)`

Comment: setImmediate(...) now exists to replace setTimeout(..., 0) . It has the same behavior but provides some semantics around your call timing.

Comment: @tohster First time scroll moving into correct position. But after that, Y offset to page value is not correct. Do you know why its happening?

Comment: onLayout is preferred way to do this

Comment: Does this work on android? I have tried to get the relative-to-parent position (fy) and getting 0. On ios working good.

Comment: and using hooks?

Comment: you can also just measure in the `onLayout` callback of an element. The benefit of it is that there is no need to fix faulty behavior with a `setTimeout` + no need for a `useEffect`, which I also kinda like.

Answer (score 105):

You can use [`onLayout`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#onlayout) to get the width, height, and *relative-to-parent* position of a component at the earliest moment that they're available:

```
<View
  onLayout={event => {
    const layout = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    console.log('height:', layout.height);
    console.log('width:', layout.width);
    console.log('x:', layout.x);
    console.log('y:', layout.y);
  }}
>
```

Compared to [using `.measure()` as shown in the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751446/1709587), this has the advantage that you'll never have to fiddle around deferring your `.measure()` calls with `setTimeout` to make sure that the measurements are available, but the disadvantage that it doesn't give you offsets relative to the entire page, only ones relative to the element's parent.

Comment: You can combine the answers - in the onLayout call measure()

Comment: x, y always 0 with onlayout?

Answer (score 40):

I had a similar problem and solved it by combining the answers above

```
class FeedPost extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    ...
    this.handleLayoutChange = this.handleLayoutChange.bind(this);
  }


handleLayoutChange() {
    this.feedPost.measure( (fx, fy, width, height, px, py) => {
      console.log('Component width is: ' + width)
      console.log('Component height is: ' + height)
      console.log('X offset to page: ' + px)
      console.log('Y offset to page: ' + py)
    })
  }

  render {
    return(
      <View onLayout={(event) => {this.handleLayoutChange(event) }} 
      ref={view => { this.feedPost = view; }} >
...
```

Now I can see the position of my feedPost element in the logs:

```
08-24 11:15:36.838  3727 27838 I ReactNativeJS: Component width is: 156
08-24 11:15:36.838  3727 27838 I ReactNativeJS: Component height is: 206
08-24 11:15:36.838  3727 27838 I ReactNativeJS: X offset to page: 188
08-24 11:15:36.838  3727 27838 I ReactNativeJS: Y offset to page: 870
```

Comment: Where does the this.feedPost variable come from? Do you initialize it somewhere? I'm getting undefined is not a function this.feedPost.measure immediately when I run my app

Comment: in the render method in the return part I have the root View: 
```<View onLayout {(event) => {this.handleLayoutChange(event) }}  ref={view => { this.feedPost = view; }} > ....```

This main View is this.feedPost.

Comment: @jsparks feedPost is the class name : class FeedPost

Comment: I think we don't need to pass event to handleLayoutChange since it does not use it right?

Comment: Thanks! For functional components you need to use `const viewRef = useRef<View>(null);` at the top and then `ref={viewRef}` on the component

Answer (score 22):

I needed to find the position of an element inside a ListView and used this snippet that works kind of like `.offset`:

```
const UIManager = require('NativeModules').UIManager;
const handle = React.findNodeHandle(this.refs.myElement);
UIManager.measureLayoutRelativeToParent(
  handle, 
  (e) => {console.error(e)}, 
  (x, y, w, h) => {
    console.log('offset', x, y, w, h);
  });
```

This assumes I had a `ref='myElement'` on my component.

Comment: Note that - like the accepted answer - you may need to wrap the call to `UIManager.measureLayoutRelativeToParent` in a `setTimeout` call to prevent it from erroring out if you're executing this code from a point in the component's lifecycle prior to it having been rendered. Note also that for modern React Native you'll want to do `import { UIManager, findNodeHandler } from 'react-native'` rather than the requires shown here.

Comment: `UIManager` and `findNodeHandle` can now be imported directly from "react-native". i.e., `import { UIManager, findNodeHandle} from "react-native"`

Comment: This method uses APIs which are now deprecated. Please use `event.target.measure`, and for TypeScript users make your ref a `View` type to access the `measure` methods.

Answer (score 17):

If you use function components and don't want to use a `forwardRef` to measure your component's *absolute* layout, you can get a reference to it from the `LayoutChangeEvent` in the `onLayout` callback.

This way, you can get the *absolute* position of the element:

```js
<MyFunctionComp
  onLayout={(event) => {
    event.target.measure(
      (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        doSomethingWithAbsolutePosition({
          x: x + pageX, 
          y: y + pageY,
        });
      },
    );
  }}
/>
```

Tested with React Native 0.63.3.

Comment: Just tried  it on Android and RN 0.63.3 and it gives wrong values (x and y with value 0 for example).

Comment: @Żabojad try this ```ref.current.measure((width, height, px, py, fx, fy)  => {console.log(fx, fy, width, height, px, py)}```

Answer (score 6):

There is a measureInWindow property on the ref argument object that can be used like so:

```
const [offset, setOffset] = React.useState();

<View ref={(view) =>
    if(!view) return;
    view.measureInWindow((x, y) => {
        setOffset({ x, y });
    })
}>
</View>
```

Answer (score 5):

This seems to have changed in the latest version of React Native when using refs to calculate.

Declare refs this way.

```
  <View
    ref={(image) => {
    this._image = image
  }}>
```

And find the value this way.

```
  _measure = () => {
    this._image._component.measure((width, height, px, py, fx, fy) => {
      const location = {
        fx: fx,
        fy: fy,
        px: px,
        py: py,
        width: width,
        height: height
      }
      console.log(location)
    })
  }
```

Comment: -1; I can't repro the need to use `._component` in React Native 0.51 (current latest release, released 3 days before you posted this answer). Not sure where you're getting that from; for me, the first argument to the `ref` callback *is* a component with a `.measure` method.

Comment: @MarkAmery you need it if you're using `Animated.View` instead of `View`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me.

1. Get position on layout.

```js
// ...
const [position, setPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
// ...
return (
  // ...
  <View
    onLayout={event => {
      event.target.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setPosition({x: x + pageX, y: y + pageY});
      });
    }}
  />
  // ...
);
```

2. Get Position on call.

```js
const ref = useRef(null);
// ...
const [position, setPosition] = useState({x: 0, y: 0});
// ...
return (
  // ...
  <TouchableOpacity
    ref={ref}
    activeOpacity={0.75}
    onPress={() => {
      ref.current.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        setPosition({x: x + pageX, y: y + pageY});
      });
    }}
  />
  // ...
);
```