# React Native - Get the position of a component in the View

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to get the position of a component in react native.

Say I have a view:

```js
<ScrollView>
    lots of items...
    lots of items...
    lots of items...
    <View></View>
</ScrollView>
```

In the end I want to be able to eventually scroll to where the View is.

This link shows how to get the position using the native ui manager, however when ran it returns:

"Attempted to measure layout but offset or dimensions were NaN"

[React Native: Getting the position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element)

I've attempted

```js
this.refs.VIEW.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
    //ox ... py all = 0
});
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sometimes if you're using measure in componentDidMount you have to wrap it in a setTimeout:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
    this.refs.VIEW.measure((ox, oy, width, height, px, py) => {
    });
}, 0);
```

Comment: This must mean the components are being loaded asynch and not really fully loaded when component did mount was called. setTimeout throws the function onto the event loop eventually making it processed after the components are fully layed out?

Comment: `this.refs` is no longer valid... I tried the following https://snack.expo.io/ryywtvoTb without luck

Answer (score 13):

You might want to use the onLayout callback on the View component. setTimeout may not work 100% of the time.

```js
<View onLayout={this.measureMyComponent} />
```

Comment: It does not help for me. I still get 0 for x and y.  Any other ideas?

Comment: It appears to get the co-ordinates relative to the thing that contains it. So if it is at `{ left: 0, top: 0 }` relative to the View that contains it, then x and y will both be 0.