# Programmatic scrolling in react-native

Tags: react-native

Is there a way to programatically scroll to bring an element into view, either inside a ListView or ScrollView?

I'm using react-native 0.2+

Comment: There's iOS / Android `.scrollTo({x:number, y:number, animated:bool})` (syntax since 0.19 I guess) implemented for ScrollView. Use it. You need coordinates of an element for it - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element

Comment: Have you ever found a solution to this? I would be interested in scrolling to element in a ListView where the height of the items is not uniform.