# How to get the position of a component on screen in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am working on a react native app and I want to handle touches on screen.

One use case is when the user "press" on screen, I want to be able to get the position (x,y) of a specific component on screen to know if it matches the (x,y) of the touch.

I've searched already on stack overflow, but none of the given solutions worked...

In my root component:

```
_onPress = () => {
    // How can I get the position of my component ?
    this._myComponent.xxx();
};

render() {
    return (
        <View><MyComponent ref={(r) => this._myComponent = r;} /></View>
    );
}
```

**EDIT:**
After trying this solution ([React Native: Getting the position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element)) I made it work as follow:

In MyComponent.js:

```
getPosition () => {
    this._ref._component.measure((width, height, px, py, fx, fy) => {
        const location = {
            fx: fx,
            fy: fy,
            px: px,
            py: py,
            width: width,
            height: height
        }
        console.log(location)
    });
};

render() {
    return (
        <View ref={(r) => { this._ref = r;} } />
    );
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32751446/1287643

Comment: I've tried this solution and it doesn't work in my app for some reason, I don't really know why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### React Native

You can use `.measure()`:

```
this._myComponent._component.measure((width, height, px, py, fx, fy) => {
  // do positioning checks here
}
```

> Determines the location on screen, width, and height of the given view and returns the values via an async callback. If successful, the callback will be called with the following arguments: `x`, `y`, `width`, `height`, `pageX`, `pageY`.

Docs: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html#other-native-methods

---

#### Web API (no React Native)

If you're working with a DOM node, you can use `Element.getBoundingClientRect()`:

```
let domRect = this._myComponent.getBoundingClientRect();
let { x, y } = domRect;
```

> The result is the smallest rectangle which contains the entire element, with read-only left, top, right, bottom, x, y, width, and height properties describing the overall border-box in pixels. Properties other than width and height are relative to the top-left of the viewport.

Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect

Comment: The question is about React Native, not React DOM. Will this solution work in React Native?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the tag. I'm not sure about React Native. This is what I found on the docs, it might help: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/dimensions.html

Comment: It doesn't work in my case because I am using react native, so this is no dom elements.
The 'Dimensions' API is useful to get the width and height of the viewport and not its coordinates.

Comment: @AlexisSantini this SO question has what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element

Comment: I've updated my answer with the right solution for React Native

Comment: Ok so I tried both solutions and the one in your previous comment worked (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element).

Comment: However, I tried your update and it tells me 'this._myComponent.measure' is not a function

Comment: My bad, I think it should be `this._myComponent._component.measure(...)` — can you confirm that it works for you?

Comment: Yes it does!

After reading between the lines in the react native doc, I came to this conclusion:

The difference between calling: this._myComponent.measure() & this._myComponent._component.measure() is in the fact that in this case MyComponent renders an "Animated.View" instead of a View and the measure function can be called on any View, but if you want to call it on something else (eg. Not a "native view") you can by referencing this "_component" property.

Comment: Cool, glad to hear it worked :) I'll update my answer again then

Answer (score 5):

For an example in a functional component using useRef in React Native:

```
const BoardSquare = props => {
  const squareRef = useRef(null);

  console.log('squareRef', squareRef);

  const doMeasure = square => {
    squareRef.current.measure((width, height, px, py, fx, fy) => {
      const location = {
        fx: fx,
        fy: fy,
        px: px,
        py: py,
        width: width,
        height: height,
      };
      console.log('location', location);
      square.x = fx;
      square.y = fy;
      square.xMax = fx + px;
      square.yMax = fy + py;
    });
  };

  return (
    <Square
      {...props}
      ref={squareRef}
      filled={props.square.filled}
      onLayout={() => doMeasure(props.square)}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use both `onLayout` and the react native `Dimensions` to get the latest layout, dimensions or positions across web and mobile, especially with web having the ability to resize the window.

```
import { useRef, useState, useCallback, useEffect } from 'react'
import { View, Dimensions } from 'react-native'

const viewRef = useRef<View>(null)
const [layout, setLayout] = useState<any>(null)

const measureLayout = useCallback(() => {
    viewRef.current?.measure((
        x, y,
        width, height,
        pageX, pageY
    ) => {
       setLayout({
           x, y,
           width, height,
           pageX, pageY
       })
    })
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    const sub = Dimensions.addEventListener(
        'change',
        ({window,screen}) => {
            measureLayout()
        }
    )
    return () => sub?.remove()
}, [])

return (
    <View
        ref={viewRef}
        onLayout={measureLayout}
    />
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `onLayout`. Example

```js
const [viewHeight, setViewHeight] = React.useState(0);
return (
  <View
    onLayout={e => {
      e.persist();
      setViewHeight(e && e.nativeEvent ? e.nativeEvent.layout.height : 0);
    }}
  />
);
```

[A more in-depth example](https://www.matthewsessions.com/blog/react-native-on-layout/)

[Documentation of `LayoutEvent`](https://reactnative.dev/docs/layoutevent)