# React Native - How to automatically scroll the ScrollView to the cursor position?

Tags: react-native

If I have a `ScrollView` and inside that `ScrollView` I have many `TextInput`, how can I scroll the `ScrollView` to the cursor position when user taps any of `TextInput` and start typing?

Anytime an user is typing and the cursor passes the `ScrollView`'s visible portion, scroll the `ScrollView` to make the user can see the cursor.

How can I do that?

Comment: I've put a bounty on this issue since I'm experiencing the same problem. The solutions I have seen in here has only solved the issue for one TextInput and I need a working solution for multiple TextInputs on the same ScrollView.

Comment: It is not perfect but `react-native-gesture-handler` has `ScrollView` and `TextInput`. I use both. They can do some work but not perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

After looking into this I might have a possible solution. There is a `scrollTo()` method for `ScrollView` which can be used to scroll to a specific position on the screen. And there is a `measure()` method which can be used to determine a position of a component on a screen. So, you can get the position of the `textInput` component when it is `onFocus` and trigger a function which then call the `scrollTo()` method of the `ScrollView`.

I haven't tried it so not 100% sure about this.

Resources:
[How to get the position of a component on screen in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47471308/how-to-get-the-position-of-a-component-on-screen-in-react-native)
https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto

Answer (score 0):

## Using References

I have noticed some work arounds such as providing absolute co-ordinates of the component and then adjusting the function and corresponding co-ordinates of the child component from device to device. This is a temporary fix and not really desirable. Here's when the `references` come into picture.

```
<Component
    ref={ref => {
      this.compRef = ref;
    }}
/>
```

once you assign a ref to particular component, you can use react-native's `scrollTo()` https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#scrollto  in order to invoke the scroll event in the UI.

```
this.compRef.scrollTo({
    //...props here
});
```

in case one is using functional components, leverage the `useRef()` https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect  hook to pass references and use them for scrolling.

In order to ship a production ready code, deep linking is always recommended. For more info regarding how to use references and how to connect them with the `scrollTo()` function in `scrollView` find an example here: https://arsfutura.com/magazine/deep-linking-in-react-native-scroll-to-element/

[image]

source: https://arsfutura.com/magazine/deep-linking-in-react-native-scroll-to-element/