# can I get the position of a `View` after layout in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Is there a way to get a `View`'s frame after layout? I'd like to draw a line connecting two views after layout has positioned them:

[image]

It seems I need something like [`measure`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element/32751446#32751446) in React.

Comment: @Fogmeister I mean a line connecting the two views. I updated the question.

Comment: @Fogmeister picture added :)

Comment: Ah... I see now. Much clearer with the picture added.

Comment: @Taylor deleted my answer as it wasn't that clear before the picture

Comment: @MatteoPacini sorry for being unclear initially.

Comment: Interesting problem though. As the views in your cods are not actually views. They are just an instruction set of how to create the views (or whatever they are) when they are added to the screen. I wonder if there's is a new way of inspecting views too. Like the equivalent of "viewDidAppear" etc... But maybe through accessing some osrt of closure and passing it into the "view"? Or something?

Comment: Or maybe this is a sign that you should be using some other technology? Like SpriteKit for instance? Or just rending the views yourself without SwiftUI? Or just fall back to UIKit in this case? What is the app that you're creating?

Comment: @Fogmeister It's already created http://audulus.com :)

Comment: @Taylor Could you please add a snippet of how you've drawn a line between two views? The answer by Jake is really not that self-explanatory and is very short and I just cannot find anything that explains this well. Would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use a `GeometryReader` to get the frame of each view and use the frame to determine the points for a path between the two views.

```
struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
            let frame = geometry.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.local)
            return Text("\(frame.origin.x), \(frame.origin.y), \(frame.size.width), \(frame.size.height)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You’re returning a frame as a _string_?

Comment: I'm returning a `Text` view (i.e. SwiftUI's version of `UILabel`) that displays the frame on the screen as an example.

Comment: Would `CoordinateSpace.global` be better?

Comment: I assumed the path being drawn would be under a local coordinate space so it made sense to get the frame in the local coordinate space as well. But it really depends on the view hierarchy I think. Global would def be useful in many scenarios.

Comment: Is GeometryReader supposed to work if you use it for example inside an HStack, will it layout the sister views first and then call the GeometryReader? And is there some way to get the laid out geometry of a daughter view?

Comment: Does this approach actually work? How would you access the values you get from the GeometryReader, from _outside_ the view? That is where you need it, right?

Comment: @Gusutafu state.

Comment: When I use GeometryReader on a view the view becomes misplaced.

Comment: @Gusutafu See my answer below for an approach how to get the data where you need it

Answer (score 4):

To export the "as rendered" view coordinates, I created a set of arrays for the x,y coordinates, and saved them in the Model object. However, I had to NOT encapsulate them in @Published var, instead kept them as just "var", otherwise you get into an infinite loop of updating the coordinates and then re-rendering the view.

Using Apple's 'landmark' tutorial, the Model object was modified as follows:

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

final class UserData: ObservableObject {
  @Published var showFavoritesOnly = false
  @Published var landmarks = landmarkData
 var circleImageX = Array(repeating: 0.0, count:20)
 var circleImageY = Array(repeating: 0.0, count:20)

}
```

Then, write to those arrays each time the CircleImage.swift is rendered using the following code, again from the 'landmark.swift' tutorial, saving the frame midpoints.

```
import SwiftUI

struct CircleImage: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
  var landmark: Landmark

  var landmarkIndex: Int {
    userData.landmarks.firstIndex(where: {$0.id == landmark.id})!
  }
  var body: some View {

    ZStack {
      landmark.image
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4))
        .shadow(radius: 10)
      VStack {

        GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
          let frame = geometry.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global)
          self.userData.circleImageX[self.landmarkIndex] = Double(frame.midX)
          return
            Text("\(frame.midX)")
              .foregroundColor(.red)
              .bold()
              .font(.title)
        }
        .offset(x: 0.0, y: 50.0)
        GeometryReader { geometry -> Text in
          let frame = geometry.frame(in: CoordinateSpace.global)
          self.userData.circleImageY[self.landmarkIndex] = Double(frame.midY)
          return
            Text("\(frame.midY)")
              .foregroundColor(.red)
              .bold()
              .font(.title)
        }
        .offset(x: 0.0, y: -50.0)
      }
    }
  }
}`
```

Not only does this save the rendered coordinates, it also renders them as a Text view overlaid with the image as suggested by Jake.
Naturally you can delete the Text overlay view once you're satisfied the coordinates are correct.
Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

```
struct LineView: View {
    
    @State private var viewFrames: [CGRect] = [.zero, .zero, .zero]
    @State private var path: Path? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("View 1")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Color.blue.onAppear {
                                    viewFrames[0] = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                                    path = createPath()
                                }
                            })
                    Spacer()
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    Text("View 2")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(
                            GeometryReader { geometry in
                                Color.green
                                    .onAppear {
                                        viewFrames[1] = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                                        path = createPath()
                                    }
                            })
                }
                
                HStack {
                    Text("View 3")
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .background(GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Color.orange
                                .onAppear {
                                    viewFrames[2] = geometry.frame(in: .global)
                                    path = createPath()
                                }
                        })
                    Spacer()
                }
                
            }
            
            if let path = path {
                path.stroke(Color.gray, lineWidth: 3)
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    private func createPath() -> Path? {
        // Check if all frames are set.
        guard viewFrames.allSatisfy({ !$0.isEmpty }) else {
            return nil
        }
        // Calculate the center points of each view.
        let centerPoints = viewFrames.map {
            CGPoint(x: ($0.midX), y: $0.midY)
        }
        
        // Create a path connecting the center points of each view.
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: centerPoints[0])
        path.addLine(to: centerPoints[1])
        path.addLine(to: centerPoints[2])
        return path
    }
    
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

When you need a view's position outside the view itself, `PreferenceKey`s are a great way to pass that information up the view hierarchy.

`PreferenceKey`s can seem a bit daunting – but they allow to use a `GemoetryReader` in an overlay, preventing the `GeometryReader` to mess with the layout is it has a sad tendency to do.

I created this `AbsolutePositionReader` (usage below), inspired by this [amazing blog post](https://swiftui-lab.com/communicating-with-the-view-tree-part-1/):

```swift
struct AbsolutePositionReader: View {
  let id: String?
  init() { self.id = nil }
  init(_ id: String?) { self.id = id }
  
  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { metrics in
      let absolutePosition = CGPoint(
        x: metrics.frame(in: .named("AbsolutePositionReaderSpace")).midX, // use min/mid/max as needed
        y: metrics.frame(in: .named("AbsolutePositionReaderSpace")).midY  // use min/mid/max as needed
      )

      Rectangle()
        .fill(Color.clear)
        .preference(
          key: AbsolutePositionKey.self,
          value: [AbsolutePositionValue(id: id, absolutePosition: absolutePosition)]
        )
    }
  }
}

struct AbsolutePositionValue: Equatable {
  let id: String?
  let absolutePosition: CGPoint
}

struct AbsolutePositionKey: PreferenceKey {
    typealias Value = [AbsolutePositionValue]
    static var defaultValue: [AbsolutePositionValue] = []
    static func reduce(value: inout [AbsolutePositionValue], nextValue: () -> [AbsolutePositionValue]) {
        value.append(contentsOf: nextValue())
    }
}
```

This is how you use it to draw that line:

```
struct Lines: View {
  @State var box1Center: CGPoint = CGPoint()
  @State var box2Center: CGPoint = CGPoint()
  
  var body: some View {
    ZStack() {
      HStack(alignment: .top) {
        Rectangle()
          .fill(Color.blue)
          .frame(height: 100)
          .overlay(AbsolutePositionReader("box1"))
        
        Spacer()
        
        Rectangle()
          .fill(Color.red)
          .overlay(AbsolutePositionReader("box2"))
        
      }
        // Saves the positions of the boxes to the state, so we can draw the line
        .onPreferenceChange(AbsolutePositionKey.self) { preferences in
          for pref in preferences {
            if (pref.id == "box1") { box1Center = pref.absolutePosition }
            if (pref.id == "box2") { box2Center = pref.absolutePosition }
          }
        }
      
      Path { path in // Draws the actual line
        path.move(to: box1Center)
        path.addLine(to: box2Center)
      }.stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 4)
      
    }.coordinateSpace(name: "AbsolutePositionReaderSpace")
  }
}
```

[image: Result: Boxes with a line]