# How to get the position of a view in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Below I have three Text views, the location of `View 3` will be dynamic every time the app loads, and what I would like to be able to do is animate `View 2` to the exact position of `View 3` regardless of where `View 3` is on the screen.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56518425/can-i-get-the-position-of-a-view-after-layout-in-swiftui) thread but I'm not sure how to use `ReometryReader` to accomplish what I need.

How can I get the current position of `View 3`?

How can I assign the x and y position of the `View 3` to `xPosition` and `yPosition` respectively inside the withAnimation method?

```
struct PositioningViews: View {
    @State private var xPosition:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var yPosition:CGFloat = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("View 1")
                .background(.purple)
           
            Text("View 2")
                .background(.orange)
                .offset(x: xPosition, y: yPosition)
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.3).delay(0.5)) {
                        self.xPosition = 50
                        self.yPosition = 0
                    }
                }
            
            Text("View 3")
                .background(.blue)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Complete Working Code:**

```
struct PositioningViews: View {
    @State private var xPosition2:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var yPosition2:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var xPosition3:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var yPosition3:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var offsetValueX = 0.0
    @State private var offsetValueY = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("View 1")
                .background(.purple)
           
            
            Text("View 2")
                .background(.orange)
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader{ geo -> AnyView in
                        
                        AnyView(Color.clear
                            .onAppear(){
                              
                                    xPosition2 = geo.frame(in: .global).midX
                                    yPosition2 = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
                                
                                
                            })
                    }
                )

                .background(.blue)
                .offset(x: offsetValueX, y: offsetValueY)
                .onAppear(){
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        withAnimation {
                            offsetValueX = xPosition3 - xPosition2
                            offsetValueY = yPosition3 - yPosition2
                        }
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(2)
            
            
            Text("View 3")
                .background(.blue)
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader{ geo -> AnyView in
                        
                        AnyView(Color.clear
                            .onAppear(){
                               
                                xPosition3 = geo.frame(in: .global).midX
                                yPosition3 = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
                                    
                                
                            })
                    }
                )
                .zIndex(1)
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT, Without AnyView:**

```
struct PositioningViews: View {
    @State private var xPosition2:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var yPosition2:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var xPosition3:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var yPosition3:CGFloat = 0
    @State private var offsetValueX = 0.0
    @State private var offsetValueY = 0.0
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text("View 1")
                .background(.purple)
           
            
            Text("View 2")
                .background(.orange)
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader{ geo  in
                        Color.clear
                            .onAppear(){
                                xPosition2 = geo.frame(in: .global).midX
                                yPosition2 = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
                            }
                    }
                )
                .background(.blue)
                .offset(x: offsetValueX, y: offsetValueY)
                .onAppear(){
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) {
                        withAnimation {
                            offsetValueX = xPosition3 - xPosition2
                            offsetValueY = yPosition3 - yPosition2
                        }
                    }
                }
                .zIndex(2)
            
            Text("View 3")
                .background(.blue)
                .overlay(
                    GeometryReader{ geo in
                       Color.clear
                            .onAppear(){
                                xPosition3 = geo.frame(in: .global).midX
                                yPosition3 = geo.frame(in: .global).midY
                                    
                            }
                    }
                )
                .zIndex(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It did the trick.  I actually removed the `AnyView` return, changed `.overlay` for `.background`and removed the delay `DispatchQueue.main...` and it still works fine. Is there any reason why you added the delay and `AnyView`?  I just removed them since it looks cleaner. Thanks a lot for the good example, it helps me a lot to understand how `GeometryReader` works.