# .measure is not a function

Tags: react-native

I want to determine the position of my element from top of the screen. From other questions, one way to do is by using .measure property of react native?

Ref Question: [React Native: Getting the position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element)

So I did something like this

```
const AutoComplete = (props) => {
  let parentViewRef =  useRef(null);
  return (
       <View 
        style={styles.modelOpenViewMain}>
        <View  ref={parentViewRef} 
        onLayout={({nativeEvent}) => {
          console.log(nativeEvent)
          if (parentViewRef) {
            parentViewRef.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
                      console.log(x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
             })
            }}}/>
        <View style={styles.modelOpenInputView}>
          <TextInput
              value={value.label}
              onChangeText={(text) => onchangeHandler(text)}
              style={[{color: defaultColor, borderColor: defaultColor}, styles.defaultTextInputStyle, textInputStyle]}
            />
          </View>
      </View>
)
}
```

console for my parentViewRef is giving me this `console.log(parentViewRef)`

```
_nativeTag: 73
_children: []
viewConfig:
uiViewClassName: "RCTView"
Commands: {}
bubblingEventTypes: {topSelect: {…}, topBlur: {…}, topChange: {…}, topEndEditing: {…}, topFocus: {…}, …}
directEventTypes: {topClick: {…}, topContentSizeChange: {…}, topLoadingError: {…}, topLoadingFinish: {…}, topLoadingStart: {…}, …}
validAttributes: {hasTVPreferredFocus: true, focusable: true, nativeBackgroundAndroid: true, nativeForeg
```

And there isn't any function measure in there, Can someone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong?

Just in case: I am logging my parentViewRef after 3 seconds

```
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(parentViewRef)
 }, 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning `onLayout` prop already, you can have `y` from there

```
onLayout={({ nativeEvent }) => console.log(nativeEvent.layout.y)}
```

`.measure` (if you still need it, but I imagine you don't) should be called at some point later in time in respond to some event, but after onLayout was executed at least once

Comment: `y` is coming out to be zero

Comment: and measure is still undefined. I am calling `onChangeText` event.

Comment: `y` returns the value of position inside parent

Answer (score 0):

When using a ref, you need to access the referenced object using `parentViewRef.current`. In your case `parentViewRef.current.measure`.

I have the same issue with measure being undefined, so I'm not sure if that solves your problem, unfortunately it didn't solve mine