# Move Xposition of View from 0 to its origianl position in React Native

Tags: react-native, use-effect, react-animated, react-animations

```
const valueX = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current

  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing( valueX , {
      toValue  :  // How to get the original X position of the component here.
      duration : 1000,
      easing  : Easing.linear
    }).start()
  }, [])
```

So, I have a component (i.e View) originally at some position on the screen. I wanted to have a slight animation there using react native animated API. What I want is to **move X position of that view from 0 to its original position** . How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need the position of the element - set that as your state and then change it in the way you want. Check out this question to get the elements position.

[React Native: Getting the position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element)