# ReactNative - Find views absolute position after it is scrolled/moved?

Tags: react-native

I am trying to find the absolute position of a view. I can easily get its position using `onLayout` ([#1](https://reactnative.dev/docs/view#onlayout) [#2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element))

But this only gives the initial rendering position, but if the view is moved around due to scrolling, `onLayout` function is not firing again.

Can anyone please tell me if there is a way to get the absolute position after a change in view's position?
It will be awesome if there is a function or something that I can call with the view and, it will give its position.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RCTUIManager does this same thing. Check out this [example](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1374#issuecomment-104744814).

Comment: Also first answer on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element does same