# React Native onLayout x and y are not correct

Tags: react-native, drag-and-drop, draggable, panresponder

I am using the React Native `PanResponder` class to allow for drag and drop if elements of the screen.

What I have discovered is that the `onLayout` is not returning the x absolute positions, it's being affected by its parent views and is returning weird results.

For example the current view has 3 columns and the `onLayout` resides in the middle column. It is returning it's x value as 146.5. Which is not the absolute position.

How would I get the absolute position of the element if it resides in multiple parent views?

```
// Omitted some code for clarity

const dropZoneValues = React.useRef(null);

const pan = React.useRef(new Animated.ValueXY());

const setDropZoneValues = React.useCallback((event) =>
{
    dropZoneValues.current = event.nativeEvent.layout;

}, []);



return (
    <Main background={bg} showHeader={false}>


        <Row rowStyles={{
            textAlign: 'center', marginLeft: 50, marginRight: 50,
            alignSelf: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            justifyContent: 'center',
        }}>

            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={4}>
            </Col>
            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={4}>

                <View
                    onLayout={setDropZoneValues}
                    style={styles.dropZone}>
                    <Text style={styles.text}>Drop me here!</Text>
                </View>

                {renderDraggable()}

            </Col>

            <Col xs={4} sm={4} md={4} lg={4}>
            </Col>

        </Row>

    </Main>

);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    mainContainer: {
        flex: 1,
        padding: 20,
        flexDirection: 'column',
    },
    dropZone: {
        height: 100,
        backgroundColor: '#2c3e50',
        width: 100,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        position: 'absolute',
    },
    text: {
        marginTop: 25,
        marginLeft: 5,
        marginRight: 5,
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: '#fff'
    },
    draggableContainer: {
        zIndex: 99999
    },
    circle: {
        backgroundColor: '#1abc9c',
        width: 80,
        height: 80,
        borderRadius: CIRCLE_RADIUS,
        zIndex: 99999,
        position: 'absolute'
    }

});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Native: Getting the position of an element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096038/react-native-getting-the-position-of-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

`onLayout` returns positions relative to parents. You can instead use `event.target.measure` within the `onLayout` callback to find the absolute position (though note this is marginally worse for performance).

```
<MyComponent
  onLayout={(event) => {
    event.target.measure(
      (x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
        doSomethingWithAbsolutePosition({
          x: pageX, 
          y: pageY,
        });
      },
    );
  }}
/>
```

(hat tip to https://stackoverflow.com/a/64882955/842506)