# React-native how to move screen up on textinput

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a login screen created using react-native.

How can I shift my screen up when the user is typing in the textInput?

Do I listen to the onFocus() event and use css styling to change the style of the view?

Comment: We need more context/code here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to auto-slide the window out from behind keyboard when TextInput has focus?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313244/how-to-auto-slide-the-window-out-from-behind-keyboard-when-textinput-has-focus)

Comment: You may want to theck [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3195#issuecomment-146568644) Github issue. We're discussing how to achieve this in there.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In 2017 (RN 0.43) there is special component for this: [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview)

Comment: @farmcommand2 it works, but with some hacks. There is [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/11681#issuecomment-339446150) on GitHub with solutions. I use this one: `behavior={(Platform.OS === 'ios') ? 'padding' : null}`

Comment: Kind of crappy. I'd rather implement the keyboard event by myself. so you really do have control over the behaviour of your Layout

Comment: As of December 2018, it seems to be working in Android as well.

Comment: Unfortunately KeyboardAvoidingView is a pure garbage and does not really work.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html) to control screen up and down movements. As long as user hasn't focused any `TextInput`, you can [disable scroll](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#scrollenabled). On focus, just shift up the scrollview using [Content Offset](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentoffset) prop.

```html
<TextInput
    onFocus={this.textInputFocused.bind(this)}
  />

textInputFocused() {
//do your stuff here. scroll screen up
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 7):

```
import {KeyboardAvoidingView} from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView style={styles.container} behavior="padding" enabled>

    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 30}}> test text before input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 30}}> test text before input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 30}}> test text before input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 30}}> test text before input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 30}}> test text before input</Text>

    <TextInput
        style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
        onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
        value={this.state.text}
    />

    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 20}}>1 test text after input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 20}}>2 test text after input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 20}}>3 test text after input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 20}}>4 test text after input</Text>
    <Text style={{height: 100, marginTop: 20}}>5 test text after input</Text>

</KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

Run in snack :
https://snack.expo.io/H1BE5ZoXV

Answer (score 6):

Night Fury's answer is pretty good, though wouldn't fuss with the ScrollView's `contentOffset`, I'd use the `ScrollResponder`:

```jsx
render() {
  return (
    <ScrollView ref="myScrollView">
      <TextInput
        ref="myInput"
        onFocus={this._scrollToInput.bind(this)}
      />
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

_scrollToInput {
  const scrollResponder = this.refs.myScrollView.getScrollResponder();
  const inputHandle = React.findNodeHandle(this.refs.myInput)

  scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
    inputHandle, // The TextInput node handle
    0, // The scroll view's bottom "contentInset" (default 0)
    true // Prevent negative scrolling
  );
}
```

See the method definition: [scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/71f32fb5a34f3841621abbeed8fe6f50b32402be/Libraries/Components/ScrollResponder.js#L434-L453)

Comment: This will bust on getScrollResponder I'm guessing this is worked on an older version of the api. I use scrollTo and hard code the numbers its a horrible solution and I'm half tempted to just use webviews for form pages.

Comment: It works fine to move the screen up, what should I use to move screen down again after finishes typing?

Answer (score 1):

This [package](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view) does a greate job, introduces a KeyboardAwareScrollView component that scrolls the view up matching the input with the keyboard, then scrolling back down.

Answer (score 0):

And another solution, working with RN 0.2, this time instead of squashing the content it scrolls.

```
 inputFocused: function(ref) {
   this._scroll(ref, 75);
 },

 inputBlurred: function(ref) {
   this._scroll(ref, 0);
 },

 _scroll: function(ref, offset) {
   setTimeout(() => {
     var scrollResponder = this.refs.myScrollView.getScrollResponder();
     scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
                React.findNodeHandle(this.refs[ref]),
                offset,
                true
            );
     });
  },
```

...

```
render: function() {
  return <View style={{flex: 1}}> 
    <ScrollView ref="myScrollView" keyboardDismissMode='interactive' contentContainerStyle={{flex: 1}}>
      <TextInput
        ref="myInput"
        onFocus={this.inputFocused.bind(this, 'myInput')}
        onBlur={this.inputBlurred.bind(this, 'myInput')} />
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a crap shoot to get the native keyboard awareness functionality of ScrollView working. For my Android app, it works perfectly in one screen that is nearly identical as the other for which doesn't work. And on iOS, it just doesn't work. This is what's working for me:

```
import { Keyboard, ScrollView, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

this.state = {
    filler: false,
}

componentWillMount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide.bind(this));
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
}

_keyboardDidShow() {
    this.setState({filler: true})
    setTimeout(() => this.vertical && this.vertical.scrollToEnd({animated: true}), 0);
}

_keyboardDidHide() {
    this.setState({filler: false})
}


...
return (
  <ScrollView ref={ref => this.vertical = ref}>
    <TextInput/>
    { this.state.filler ? <View style={styles.filler}/> : null }
  </ScrollView>
)

styles.filler = {
    height: 'Keyboard Height'
}
```

Note: This might only work if your `<TextInput/>` is at the bottom of the screen which it was in my case.

Comment: use arrow function from es6 to avoid the bind method https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192682/react-js-es6-avoid-binding-this-to-every-method
And you can also improve it by implementing `keyboardWillShow' on iOS. (isn't implemented on Android)

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I was noticing that the response frame of the TextInput appearing above the keyboard was a bit behind. Thanks!