# React.js ES6 avoid binding 'this' to every method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Recently, I've started tinkering with React.js and I love it. I started out in the regular ES5, so as to get the hang of things, the docs are all written in ES5...

But now I wanted to try ES6, because it's shiny and new, and it does seem to simplify some things. What bothers me a lot is that for every method I had added into my component classes I now have to bind 'this' to, otherwise it doesn't work. So my constructor ends up looking like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = { ...some initial state... }

  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
  this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
}
```

If I were to add even more methods to my class, this would become an even bigger, uglier mess.

My question is, is there some way to get around this, or at least make it easier, shorter and less ugly? One of the main reasons I wanted to try React with ES6 was to make my code more concise, but this is doing the opposite. Any suggestions or input would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you really using *all* of your methods as handlers somewhere?

Comment: See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31368520/1048572)

Comment: Well this was taken from a higher level component, so yes, they are all being used somewhere down the hierarchy. I tried to follow their philosophy and tried to best figure out which component needs to know what, and this was what I ended up with.

Comment: But aren't (shouldn't) they be called as methods on the component object, instead of being passed around as functions?

Comment: This answer doesn't really help me at all. The only usable new thing there is that I would define all my methods within the constructor, but that would make the code even more unreadable.

Comment: From what I gathered from reading the React documentation, handlers should be defined at the most top level component where it needs to have effects. Which makes perfect sense, because data flow in React is purely one directional, children can't invoke their parents' methods in any other way.

Comment: Well, arrow functions are the best what ES6 has to offer here. Of course, you could also do your `.bind()` calls in a loop if you are looking for something shorter.

Comment: It seems a loop may be the best alternative in a base class. That's a shame though. Thank you.

Comment: I personally use decorators ([specifically `autobind`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators#autobind)) for this instead of class property initializers.

Comment: Thank you, that is actually a very great solution as well. Will definitely give it a shot.

Comment: I am now wondering why this wasn't a problem in ES5?

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/react-binding-revealed-aa458df8c136#.fd5z0vmjl

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You can use [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) to do the binding outside the constructor. They look like the following:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {

  handleBar = () => {
    console.log('neat');
  };

  handleFoo = () => {
    console.log('cool');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        onClick={this.handleBar}
        onMouseOver={this.handleFoo}
      />
    );
  }

}
```

Class fields are supported experimentally by Babel via its [class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/), but they are still "experimental" because they are a [Stage 3 Draft](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-fields/) (not yet in a Babel preset).

You will need to do the binding manually until ES7 or until enabling the feature in Babel, however. This topic is covered briefly in Babel's blog post on [React on ES6+](https://babeljs.io/blog/2015/07/07/react-on-es6-plus#arrow-functions).

Comment: Thank you. That's a shame. I use gulp as my build system and it seems as though the gulp package doesn't have that option. Any suggestions on how to make this more bearable?

Comment: Which Gulp package is that?

Comment: gulp-babel. I didn't realise there were multiple versions.

Comment: It looks like you can add "es7.classProperties" to the `options.optional` Array to enable the transform when calling `babel`. See [experimental usage](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/#usage).

Comment: Oh yes, so you can. I ran it with `babel({ stage: 0 })` and it worked. This seems like a temporary solution, since it is in its earliest stages but it will work very well for now. Thank you for your help.

Comment: `babel({ optional: [ 'es7.classProperties' ]})` might enable just the class properties feature if you are wary of using all stage 0 features.

Comment: Or you can use the ultimate authority for babel options: .babelrc `{"optional": ["es7.classProperties"]}`. It works regardless of how the build occurs (grunt, gulp, direct api, cli, browserify, webpack, etc.)

Comment: Will this bind for each instance?  The React docs recommend binding only in the constructor, as performance of binding in each instance is ostensibly worse.

Comment: @Brandon They have the same effect. The `constructor` method is called every time a new instance is created, and therefore the `bind` calls happen for each instance. The React docs recommend avoiding `bind` calls in the *`render`* function because `render` is called many times on a given instance whereas the constructor is called exactly once.

Comment: ahhh that clears it up. i was under the impression it was the binding method that determined how frequently the method was bound. it makes more sense that it's the placement of the bind (ie in `constructor` or `render`). i've [created a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37645914/es6-react-will-es-nexts-autobind-bind-methods-only-once-for-each-instance) re: this difference if you'd be up for answering it

Comment: In addition to this, you can add a property in the constructor like:

`this.handleBar = this.handleBar.bind(this)`

Comment: @RossAllen is there any performance benefit of binding in constructor (as react docs suggest) over this approach? Say for a large number of components?

Comment: @DivyanshuMaithani Class property initializers are still currently a proposal, so it's not possible to say whether the native version will affect performance. However, if you're using Babel then property initializers are transpiled to assigning bound instances in the constructor; they're exactly the same: https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=react%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rDCEAjMwA1tALzQAUAlKQHwrobQMC-A3Ks0A&experimental=false&loose=false&spec=false&playground=true

Comment: This example was really helpful, also this approach makes the component look cleaner, gonna go with it :)

Comment: I don't think this is a good approach if `Foo` is heavily reused due to memory waste. Because, when you use class properties (at least until today), you are assigning a different instance of your function to each instance which is pretty different than assigning it to the prototype. When you create a class method, your function is assigned to the prototype and automatically bound, which is better in memory consumption perspective.

Comment: @Richard Your examples aren't equivalent though. If you used a regular class method and passed it as a callback like `onClick={this.handleBar}`, `this` would reference `window` when your class method is called because event listeners are always called in the context of the window. You *must* either bind class methods in the constructor or via arrow functions in the class declaration for `this` to reference the component instance when the method is called as a callback.

Comment: @RossAllen I have only stated the problem of using arrow function as a class property. 

My mistake was to say that it is automatically bound, which isn't if you use a reference to the function, like `{this.handleBar}`. 

You are right, if you want to use ES6 classes you must either bind class methods or using arrow functions. For me, best way is binding class methods (it could be outside the constructor, e.g. using some helpers to act like decorators, wrapping your class/instance, etc...)

Comment: @Richard Yeah, the binding is the important part. Currently arrow functions in Babel are compiled into `bind` calls in the constructor, so they are the same thing after compilation: https://babeljs.io/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=true&loose=true&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1rDCEAjMwA1tALzQAUAlKQHwrobQMC-A3Ks0A&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=false&presets=react%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=

Answer (score 12):

Another alternative is to use decorators. You declare a getter on the prototype, and on first access for an instance it defines an own property with a bound version of that function.

But there's a catch! In development it won't replace the property, it'll bind on every access. **This means you don't break react-hot-loader**. At least for me, that's pretty important.

I created a library, [class-bind](https://www.npmjs.com/package/class-bind), that provides this.

```
import {bound} from 'class-bind';

class App {
  constructor(){
    this.foo = 'bar';
  }

  @bound
  returnsFoo(){
    return this.foo;
  }

  render(){
    var returnsFoo = this.returnsFoo;
    return (
      <div>
        {returnsFoo()} === 'bar'
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Decorators too unstable for you? You can bind everything or some things with the same benefits.

```
import {bind, bindAll} from 'class-bind';

bind(App.prototype, 'returnsFoo');

// or
bindAll(App.prototype);
```

Comment: This looks pretty great. I will definitely give it a shot. I've never really looked at the hotloader, so that hasn't been an issue for me, but it does look very useful. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I created a method to organize all the "binds".

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {

    this.bindMethods([
      'updateLocationFields',
      'render',
      'loadCities',
    ]);
  }

  bindMethods(methods) {
    methods.forEach((item) => {
      this[item] = this[item].bind(this);
    });
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: >.> . . . . . .

Answer (score 1):

Ssorallen's suggestion is great but if you want another way there is:

```
    class AppCtrlRender extends Component {
        binder(...methods) { methods.forEach( (method) => this[method] = this[method].bind(this) ); }

        render() {
            var isMobile = this.state.appData.isMobile;
            var messages = this.state.appData.messages;
            return (
                <div id='AppCtrlSty' style={AppCtrlSty}>
                    React 1.3 Slider
                    <br/><br/>
                    <div className='FlexBoxWrap'>
                        <Slider isMobile={isMobile}/>
                        <JList data={messages}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

    var getAppState = function() {
        return {
            appData: AppStore.getAppData()
        };
    };

    export default class AppCtrl extends AppCtrlRender {
        constructor() {
            super();
            this.state = getAppState();
            this.binder('appStoreDidChange');
        }

        componentDidMount() {
            var navPlatform = window.navigator.platform;
            Actions.setWindowDefaults(navPlatform);
        }
        componentWillMount() { AppStore.onAny(this.appStoreDidChange); }
        componentWillUnmount() { AppStore.offAny(this.appStoreDidChange); }
        appStoreDidChange() { this.setState(getAppState()); }
    }
```

You can add any number of methods to this.binder('method1', 'method2', ...)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, this would make binding methods less painful, but it still requires me to specify which methods to bind. For the time being, ssorallens suggestion works fine, I just enabled experimental features on babel. For how long this will be a viable option, I don't know, but for now, I think it's the shortest and cleanest option.

Comment: I tested the binder method and it works great. I just renamed the method to `bindPublicMethods`, so there is some kind of informational benefit using it, cause there is no way to mark public and private methods in es6.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `stage-0` there is a function binding syntax.

```
class MyComp extends Component {

  handleClick() { console.log('doing things') }

  render() {
    return <button onClick={::this.handleClick}>Do Things</button>
  }

}
```

This destructures to `this.handleClick.call(this)`, which I think is generally performant enough.

Comment: Wow this is pretty great, but it being in stage-0 and all, I probably wouldn't advise using it for anything serious yet. I was not aware that they proposed this feature.

Comment: Definitely solid advice, but I confess I'm not too worried about it and use it liberally :D

Comment: the React docs advise against this, as putting a bind method in the `render` method of a component will force it to bind with each re-render.
"_We recommend that you bind your event handlers in the constructor so they are only bound once for every instance_"
[source](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html)

Comment: How about simple <button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}>Do Things</button> ?

Comment: there should be sugar for `<button onClick={() => this.handleClick(arguments)}>`

Comment: The above (`::`) is functionally equivalent. What would be nice is if there were sugar for passing arbitrary arguments. `<button onClick={::(this.handleClick, someVar)} />` That way your handler would be like `handleClick(e, someVar)`. @daviestar, maybe thats what you were saying.

Comment: @JonJaques what i mean is functions called at invocation time don't need to be bound, but i think there are performance issues using this technique on 1000s of elements

Answer (score 1):

One idea to avoid bind

```
class MyComp extends Component {

  render() {
    return <button onClick={e => this.handleClick(e)}>Do Things</button>
  }

}
```

disclaimer: untested, also, cannot easily handle more than one argument (in this case, there is one, event (e).

Also, this is answer is probably an example of what *not* to do, according to this article which is probably a worthwhile read:

https://daveceddia.com/avoid-bind-when-passing-props/

Comment: `onClick = {(e, arg1, arg2, arg3) => this.handleClick(e, arg1, arg2, arg3)}` would have 4 arguments.  Arrow functions can use any number of arguments.

Comment: this way a new function is being created each time render is called

Answer (score 1):

I actually prefer to imitate OOP inheritance by passing children the parent context.

```
class Parent extends Component {
  state = {happy: false}

  changeState(happy) {
    this.setState({happy})
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Child parent={this} >
    )
  }
}

class Child extends Component {
   //...
   this.props.parent.changeState(true)
}
```

$0.02,
Jon

Answer (score 0):

I use a helper function **`doBinding(this)`**, which I call in each constructor. In this example it binds `_handleChange1()` and `_handleChange2()`.

```
class NameForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        doBinding(this);
        this.state = {value1: "", value2: ""};
    }
    _handleChange1(event) {
        this.setState({value1: event.target.value});
    }
    _handleChange2(event) {
        this.setState({value2: event.target.value});
    }
    render() {
       ...
    }
}
```

The method works even if you are not using Babel.

My handler methods all begin with `_` (a convention to indicate they are private). So `doBinding()` looks for the `_`. You can remove the `if (key.startsWith("_"))` if you don't use this convention.

```
function doBinding(obj) {
    const proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    for (const key of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(proto)) {
        if (key.startsWith("_")) {
            obj[key] = obj[key].bind(obj);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using a common function to do the binding-work like this:

```
// common function:
function bind(self,methods){
     for(var key in methods){
       self[key] = methods[key].bind(self);
     }
}

// your class:
class MyClass {
     constructor() {
          bind(this,{
              someHandler1(event){ 
                //... 
              },
              someHandler2(event){ 
                //...
              }
          })
     }
}
```