# ES6 React: Will ES.Next's @autobind bind methods only once for each instance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

There are a **lot** of questions/articles written on the numerous ways to handle binding in ES6 React, but most don't seem to address a problem outlined in the [React docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) (**emphasis** mine):

> We recommend that you bind your event handlers in the constructor so
>   **they are only bound once for every instance**:
>
> ```
> constructor(props) {
>   super(props);
>   this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
>   this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
> }
> ```

For context, they're advising against in-line binding of methods, such as:

```
//using .bind()
<div onClick={this.tick.bind(this)}>

// ES6 anon arrow functions
<div onClick={() => this.tick()}>

// ES.Next :: operator
<div onClick={::this.tick}>
```

Sure. But the recommended solution of binding every method in the constructor is cumbersome w/ a lot of methods, so I was looking at the ES.Next
[@autobind decorator](https://github.com/jayphelps/core-decorators.js#autobind) at class level as a simple solution:

```
import { autobind } from 'core-decorators';

@autobind
class Person {
  getPerson() {
    return this;
  }

  getPersonAgain() {
    return this;
  }
}

let person = new Person();
let { getPerson, getPersonAgain } = person;

getPerson() === person;
// true

getPersonAgain() === person;
// true
```

What I can't figure out is:  will this decorator have the same disadvantage of in-line binding methods? i.e., will the methods be bound just once for every instance?

If not, is there a succinct solution that avoids this pitfall?

Comment: Just an FYI ES7 will not have decorators: http://www.2ality.com/2016/01/ecmascript-2016.html

Comment: This might be coming in a future version, but not ES7 (which is already finalized). Please read the tag wiki! I updated your question.

Answer (score 1):

[Class instance fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields) and their associated initializers solve the issue of having to assign properties with the same name as methods inside the constructor but with a more succinct syntax. The following example is possible with Babel's [class properties transform](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-class-properties/):

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  }
  tick = () => {
    this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
  };
  ...
 }
```

This creates a new, bound `tick` property for each `Counter` instance. This creates *the same* number of bound functions as `React.createClass` did.

Without the instance field and initializer, the effect is the same (a bound `tick` property is created for each `Counter` instance) but with more verbose syntax:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {count: props.initialCount};
  this.tick = this.tick.bind(this);
}
tick() {
  this.setState({count: this.state.count + 1});
}
```

Comment: These approaches are not equivalent: the first approach, class property arrow functions, has some disadvantages for performance and, more importantly I think, testing. See https://medium.com/@charpeni/arrow-functions-in-class-properties-might-not-be-as-great-as-we-think-3b3551c440b1 for interesting write-up.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The second version is nearly equivalent to the compiled version of the first except that, as shown in that blog post, the body of the function is moved into the constructor. I'm confused about what the "Arrow function" vs. "Bound function" is in the benchmark since the top of the blog post shows that class property w/ arrow function is compiled to a bound function. Do you know what code was used in the blog post?

Comment: I'm equally confused why the autobind decorator will be a "savior"? It calls `.bind` on the instance just like the compiled arrow function. What am I missing? https://github.com/andreypopp/autobind-decorator/blob/0e7023b9a6df0a72c43e0075871768418080698a/src/index.js

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small component that does binding all methods of other components. you can try it if you want: http://www.marouen-mhiri.com/react/autobinding-es6-classes-in-react-another-approach/