# When using React Is it preferable to use fat arrow functions or bind functions in constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, class-fields

When creating a React class, which is preferable?

```
export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.doSomething = this.doSomething.bind(this)
  }

  doSomething () { ... }
}
```

or

```
export default class Foo extends React.Component {
  doSomething = () => { ... }
}
```

A coworker of mine thinks that the latter causes memory problems because babel transpiles the code to capture `this` inside the closure, and that reference will cause the instance to not be cleaned by GC.

any thoughts about this?

Comment: How would what Babel does for `=>` functions be any different than what `.bind()` does?

Comment: Using fat arrow functions saves this inside the closure

Comment: Yes. What do you suppose `.bind()` does?

Comment: I'm looking at the transpiled code and it dosent look identical, I'm not really sure what its doing though

Comment: The point is that one way or the other, the contextual value of `this` has to be saved *somewhere*. Before `.bind()` became part of the language it was commonly  implemented with a closure, and there's no reason to suspect it's not basically the same now (though with some added behaviors).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React.js ES6 avoid binding 'this' to every method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192682/react-js-es6-avoid-binding-this-to-every-method)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The public class field syntax (so `doSomething = () => {...}`) is [not yet part of ECMAScript](https://github.com/tc39/proposals) but it is doing well and I am pretty confident that it will get there.

So using this syntax forces you to transpile, but it brings advantages:

- clear, concise syntax for expressing `this` binding
- future proof for when browsers support this
- not concerned with implementation

For me, this is a clear win. In most cases, you don't even need a `constructor(props)`, saving you from that boilerplate `super` call.

If the Babel implementation would cause memory leaks, you can be sure those would have been found and fixed quickly. You are more likely to create leaks yourself by having to write more code.

Comment: Arrow functions are part of the ES2015 spec.

Comment: @Pointy yes, but Public Class Fields are not…

Answer (score 3):

Binding in the render function causes new functions to be created on every render, this means the diffing algoritm thinks there are changes. When you bind in the constructor this does not happen.

Here you can see the compiled difference for binding with arrow and binding in the constructor:
https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&code=class%20x%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor%20(props)%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20super(props)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20this.onChange%20%3D%20this.onChange.bind(this)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%0A%20%20onChange%20()%20%7B%20console.log(%27change%20x%27)%3B%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20y%20extends%20React.Component%20%7B%0A%20%20onChange%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log(%27change%20y%27)%3B%20%7D%0A%7D

Comment: I'm not asking about binding in the render, I'm asking about using fat arrow vs binding in constructor

Comment: This is actually valuable information, I don't understand why it was downvoted.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Using fat arrow functions can cause memory leaks in the form of detached DOM nodes from my experience. Much nicer to look at but there is a significant memory cost here.

Answer (score 0):

The link here clearly highlights that officially it's safe to "Bind methods in constructor" rather than using the arrow function as a short code to achieve event binding.

Here is the link: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-without-es6.html#autobinding for reference.