# Angular 5 service apparently null inside function

Tags: function, typescript, service, angular5

The solution to this issue might be fairly simple.
This is what happens when a DBA tries to code ;)

I am using Angular 5 here is the package.json:

```
"@angular/animations": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/common": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/compiler": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/core": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/forms": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/http": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.8",
"@angular/router": "^5.2.8",
"@ngrx/effects": "^4.1.1",
"@ngrx/router-store": "^4.1.1",
"@ngrx/store": "^4.1.1",
"@ngrx/store-devtools": "^4.1.1",
"@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.7",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
"rxjs": "^5.5.6",
"zone.js": "^0.8.20"
```

I am trying to call a service inside a function.
The function works pretty well and is triggered as expected.
when I do a console.log, I find all my data inside the function as expected.
Things are getting annoying when I call a service inside the function.
The service itself as a value equal to "null"... So there I am lost :)

Here is the html:

```
<form class="autocomplete-form">
  <mat-form-field class="autocomplete-full-width">
    <input matInput placeholder="ICAO code" aria-label="Airport"  [matAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="airportCtrl">
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="loadAirport">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let airport of airports" [value]="airport">
    <span>{{ airport.icao_code }}</span> <small>{{ airport.name }} ( {{ airport.country_name }} )</small>
    </mat-option>
  </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Here is the detail of the component (Yes the service is provided inside the app.module) :

The part declared in the constructor works as expected (including the service).

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from "@angular/router";
import { Airport } from '../models/airport.model';
import { AutocompleteService } from '../../../../services/autocomplete.service'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';
import { Store, State } from "@ngrx/store";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { AirportsState } from '../models/airports-state.model';
import { 
  PolpulateSelectedAirportAction
  , POPULATE_SELECTED_AIRPORT
  , LoadingSelectedAirportData
} from '../store/airports.actions';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete-airport',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete-airport.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./autocomplete-airport.component.scss']
})


export class AutocompleteAirportComponent implements OnInit  {

airportCtrl = new FormControl();

 airports: any;
 scope: string;
service: AutocompleteService;
airport: Airport;

 constructor(private autocompleteService: AutocompleteService, private store: Store<AirportsState>,private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute){
 let options;
 this.scope = 'airport';
 this.service = autocompleteService

 this.airportCtrl.valueChanges
    .debounceTime(700) 
    .subscribe(data => {
      if (data.length > 3) {
        this.service.loadField(data, this.scope).subscribe(response =>{

            options = JSON.stringify(response);

            console.log('searchResult:' + options);
            this.airports = new Airport;
            console.log(this.airports);
            return this.airports = response;

        })
      }
    })




 }

 ngOnInit() {}

  loadAirport(airport): string | undefined {
   let apt;

   if (airport) {
    console.log('Airport ID inside loadAirport : ' + airport.id);

     this.service.displayMap(airport).subscribe(response => {
       apt = JSON.stringify(response);
      console.log('searchResult:' + apt);
  })

}


return airport ? airport.icao_code+' - '+airport.name : undefined;

}


}
```

So when the function loadairport is called, the console throws an error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayMap' of undefined
    at MatAutocomplete.AutocompleteAirportComponent.loadAirport [as displayWith]

If I test the service with if (this.service == null) it says that it is null.

Could someone help me?

Thanks a million in advance.

Comment: That's where `==` backfires. It is not `null`. It's `undefined`. Because `this` is not what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a specific case of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback).

`loadAirport` is passed as a callback to component input. Once it is passed, original `this` is lost and no longer equal to component instance it originally belonged to.

`loadAirport` should be bound to the context either by defining it as arrow method:

```
loadAirport = (airport) => {...}
```

Or by binding it to component instance in constructor:

```
constructor(...) {
  this.loadAirport = this.loadAirport.bind(this);
  ...
}
```

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881670/should-i-write-methods-as-arrow-functions-in-angulars-class/45882417#45882417), the latter is preferable for several reasons.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick and kind answer. I will investigate this.