# why we use this.setState() insted of super.setState() in react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i'm new in react and i'm notice that we use `this.setState()` instead of using `super.setState()` please i need clear explain why we use this to call super class method ??
example :

```
class Checkbox extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props)
            this.state = {
                checked: true
            }
            this.handleCheck = this.handleCheck.bind(this)
        }

        handleCheck() {
            this.setState({
                checked: !this.state.checked
            })
        }

        render() {
            var msg 
            if(this.state.checked) {
                msg = "checked"
            } else {
                msg = "not checked"
            }
            return (
                <div>
                    <input type="checkbox" 
                           onChange={this.handleCheck}
                           defaultChecked={this.state.checked}/>
                    <p>This box is {msg}</p>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

Comment: Because it inherits the superclasses methods.

Comment: so every thing we inherit from super can call them using this?

Comment: As long as you don't override it by implementing that method in your component (which never really is a problem because you only ever implement your own lifecycle methods which you shouldn't call directly).

Comment: Inheritance. You only need to use the `super` keyword in a React class constructor to be able to use the `this` keyword in the constructor. You could use it to access methods on the parent class, but there is no need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how JavaScript inheritance works. An instance of `Checkbox` child class prototypically inherits from `React.Component` parent class,  `this.setState === super.setState`.

`super.method` should be referred only if it was overridden in child class, it commonly occurs in overridden method itself:

```
method() {
  super.method(); // inherit the behaviour from parent class
  // do something else
}
```

Otherwise the use of `super.method()` can be considered semantic mistake, it shows that a developer wasn't aware of inheritance mechanisms. If a method will be overridden later, it won't be in use because of that (though it's unlikely in case of `setState`).

The use of `super.method()` also requires a developer to be aware of parent class implementation. As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501), only parent prototype methods but not instance methods are available as `super`. If parent class has instance method,

```
method = () => {...}
```

Child class will inherit it as `this.method` but there will be no `super.method`.

Comment: (It is also how inheritance works in other languages)