# Typescript decorators not working with arrow functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, decorator, typescript-decorator

I have a typescript decorator factory which console logs total time taken to execute a function, actual function execution results and parameters passed to the decorator as well.

e.g.

```
export function performaceLog(...args: any[]) {
return (target: Object, key: string, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) => {
    var msg = '';
    if (args.length != 0) {
        msg = args.map(arg => arg).join(' ');
    }

    if (descriptor === undefined) {
        descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
    }

    if (typeof descriptor.value !== 'function') {
        throw new SyntaxError('Only functions can be used with log decorators');
    }

    var originalMethod = descriptor.value.bind(target);

    descriptor.value = function() {
        var funcArgs: any = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            funcArgs[i - 0] = arguments[i];
        }
        var startTime = performance.now();
        console.log(`Begin function ${key} with params (${funcArgs}) : ${msg}`);
        var result = originalMethod.apply(this, funcArgs);
        var endTime = performance.now();
        console.log(`End function ${key}. Execution time: ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds. Return result : ${result}`);
        return result;
    };
    return descriptor;
};
}
```

I am using the above decorator with a function which is present in a class:
(considering my class has other methods as well like ctor, get, set and utils).

```
class LoggerService {
    @performaceLog('validate', 'message')
    handleMessage(message) {
        console.log(message);
        return true;
    };
}
```

Function call looks like this:

```
handleMessage('decoratorValidation');
```

This gives me perfect output as:

```
Begin function handleMessage with params (decoratorValidation) : validate message     
decoratorValidation
End function handleMessage. Execution time: 0.3000000142492354 milliseconds. 
Return result : true
```

But when I change the function handleMessage to support arrow format (ES6), it throws me an error:

```
@performaceLog('validate', 'message')
handleMessage = message => {
    console.log(message);
    return true;
};
```

Error Message:

```
Unable to resolve signature of property decorator when called as an expression.
```

I have all the parameters set correctly in my tsconfig.json. I have my entire project supporting "ES6" target and I want the decorator to support arrow functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`performaceLog` is supposed to work with prototype methods only because it relies on `descriptor`, which should be optional.

There is no `descriptor` in case of `handleMessage = message => ...` class field because it doesn't exist on class prototype. Class fields are just assigned to `this` in constructor.

This line won't work for same reason:

```
descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(target, key);
```

In order to patch arrow method in decorator, a trap should be set on class prototype. Here is an example of universal decorator that can be used with both prototype and instance methods; it uses `get`/`set` to catch proper `this` context and cache decorated function to `patchFn` variable. It returns a descriptor regardless of `descriptor` parameter:

```
function universalMethodDecorator(target: any, prop: string, descriptor?: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>): any {
    let fn;
    let patchedFn;

    if (descriptor) {
        fn = descriptor.value;
    }

    return {
        configurable: true,
        enumerable: false,
        get() {
            if (!patchedFn) {
                patchedFn = (...args) => fn.call(this, ...args);
            }
            return patchedFn; 
        },
        set(newFn) {
            patchedFn = undefined;
            fn = newFn;
        }
    };

}
```

This applies only to TypeScript decorators. Babel [legacy decorators](https://github.com/loganfsmyth/babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy) may behave differently.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501), prototype methods can be preferred to instance methods for several reasons. One of the reasons is that they can be seamlessly decorated because decorators are applied to class prototype. The only real benefit of arrow method is that it is naturally bound to class instance, but since the decorator is already in use, prototype method can be bound in decorator if needed (this is what `universalMethodDecorator` basically does; it is noop for arrow methods).

Comment: The handleMessage method does exist in a class. I just edited the question and added this info as well.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. It works when handleMessage is prototype method and doesn't work when it's not, doesn't it? This is what the answer presumes, *There is no descriptor in case of handleMessage property because it doesn't exist on class* ***prototype***.

Comment: I tried to use universalMethodDecorator here but still get the same error. Point: My decorator will always have a higher order function because I want to print the messages sent from decorator as well.

e.g.:
@performaceLog('validate', 'message')
handleMessage = msg=> {
    console.log(msg);
    return true;
};

Should print 'validate', 'message'  as well as actual function param msg.

So I will always be wrapping my decorator function with higher order function like:

Comment: I tried to use universalMethodDecorator but still get the same error. Point: My decorator will always have a higher order function because I want to print the messages sent from decorator as well.
e.g.:
    @performaceLog('validate', 'message')
    handleMessage = msg=> {
        console.log(msg);
        return true;
    };

Should print 'validate', 'message'  as well as actual function param msg.

I will always be wrapping my decorator with higher order func as:
    function performaceLog(...args: any[]) {
    function universalMethodDecorator(target, prop, descriptor){
.....
}

Comment: You shouldn't get this error if you did everything correctly. Can you provide a way to replicate this error with your current attempt (stackblitz, plunk)? It doesn't really matter if it's decorator factory or not, it just becomes higher order function and behaves the same way.

Comment: There was a small bug in my code. I got it to work now. Thanks a ton!

Comment: However I get an error in case I am not sending any argument to my decorator. 
e.g.: 

@performaceLog('validate', 'message') works very well.

But 
@performaceLog throws a runtime exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'handleMessage' of object '#<LoggerService >'". But \@performaceLog() works well.

When searched for answer, few suggests to add writable: true property to decorator which in turn returns an error "TypeError: Invalid property descriptor. Cannot both specify accessors and a value or writable attribute"

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem at plunker or stackblitz?

Comment: Here you go: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-pfx2yt?file=index.js

When used as *@performaceLog, it only shows results of my function (no decorator)
When used as @performaceLog(), it shows results of function along with decorator results i.e. time required to execute function

Comment: It is [decorator factory](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorator-factories) and it should always be used as @performaceLog(..), not @performaceLog . The question is TS but you used JS in this example. If you were using TS, you would get type error when using decorator factory incorrectly.

Comment: I am using ts but the stackblitz didn't allow me to write ts file, so  I converted it to JS. I assumed the same, that I will need to use /@performanceLog() and not /@performanceLog. But this npm module https://www.npmjs.com/package/core-decorators has /@deprecate which can be used as /@deprecate, /@deprecate() & /@deprecate(.......). I tried installing & using the same but these decorators give the error (that I mentioned in my original question) when used with property decorators defined with arrow function. It only worked with prototype methods.

Comment: It's considered a good practice to consistently use decorators with () because there may be a need to pass an argument later, and you don't want to refactor all decorator occurrences when converting a decorator to a factory (this style is promoted by some libs/frameworks for this reason, e.g. Angular). It's not always possible to determine whether a decorator was called as @performanceLog or  @performanceLog(). So creating universal decorators that can be used both ways is not a good idea, just creates a lot of mess and there may be typing problems in TS (I did this before, isn't worth it).

Comment: Alright, gotcha! Thanks a lot for helping out @estus.