# TypeScript: Uncaught TypeError: this.fnName is not a function

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am working with Typescript and have an ajax call that on Success is calling another function \ method.

```
 deleteTheseSuccess(data) {
     new Fe.Upsm.Head().showGlobalNotification("Selected Items Deleted");
     this.refreshPrintQueueGrid(); <== this is there the error existst
     (window as any).parent.refreshOperatorPrintQueueCount();
 }
```

the method call that I have pointed out above is trying to call

```
refreshPrintQueueGrid() {
    $("#PrintQueueGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    this.refreshPrintQueueStats();
}
```

This compiles without any issues in VS2017 and produces the JavaScript files accordingly

and this is the call in the JavaScript output

```
PrintQueue.prototype.refreshPrintQueueGrid = function () {
    $("#PrintQueueGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
    this.refreshPrintQueueStats();
};
```

The exact error that I get is

> Uncaught TypeError: this.refreshPrintQueueGrid is not a function.

I would be grateful if anyone can help me understand what is going wrong here and what would cause this as I will have this in a number of places over my application.

--- Edit compiled code

```
PrintQueue.prototype.refreshPrintQueueGrid = function () {
            $("#PrintQueueGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
            this.refreshPrintQueueStats();
        }
```

--- Edit 2 -- Class

```
namespace Fe.Upsm {
export class PrintQueue {


    callingView: string

    constructor(callingView: string) {

        this.callingView = callingView;

        this.documentReadyObjects();

    }

    refreshPrintQueueGrid() {
        $("#PrintQueueGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
        this.refreshPrintQueueStats();
    }

    deleteThese(ids) {

        var jsonObj = {
            ids: ids
        }

        var dataAccess = new DataAccess.AjaxDataAccessLayer(Fe.Upsm.Enums.AjaxCallType.Post,
            Fe.Upsm.Enums.AjaxDataType.json,
            "../../PrintQueue/DeletePrintQueueItems",
            jsonObj);

        dataAccess.ajaxCall(this.deleteTheseError, this.deleteTheseSuccess);

    }

    deleteTheseSuccess(data) {
        new Fe.Upsm.Head().showGlobalNotification("Selected Items Deleted");
        this.refreshPrintQueueGrid;
        (window as any).parent.refreshOperatorPrintQueueCount();
    }

    deleteTheseError(xhr) {
        alert("An Error Occurred. Failed to delete print queue items");
    }



}
```

}

Comment: Can you post the entire function/ method where you're calling `this.refreshPrintQueueStats()`? It seems that you're not in the method of a class, and so `this` is not what you think. Try, also, to make a `console.log(this)` before calling the function that throws the error, and post what the console tells you

Comment: in my opinion there is problem with "this" in many places - give us more code context.

Comment: Is your first code snippet part of a method in the PrintQueue class?

Comment: where you define `refreshPrintQueueGrid()` ?
There is also some error in line: `window as any).` (unclosed bracket)

Comment: @OscarPaz the this is calling the method in the same class. So in this instance this is the self (class)  so in this class call this method.  If i dont use this Visual Studio throws errors

Comment: This could be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485/9356258 or at least solved by the docs linked there

Comment: don't be shy - show more code

Comment: @SimonPrice, I'm sure that's what you think, and maybe what VS believes, but it's obvious it is not true. Please, do what I told you and you'll see

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski full method is there...

Comment: show the class (if you can)

Comment: Or at least, the compiled code for `deleteTheseSuccess`, and also, the code where you're calling this function. The problem might be in the calling. Are you passing `deleteTheseSuccess` as a callback?

Comment: class is 202 lines of code

Comment: ok so remove that parts of class that are not important in this question but save the structure

Comment: @OscarPaz compiled code at the bottom of the question

Comment: in your class method `refreshPrintQueueGrid` is not defined

Comment: its there... i deleted that by accident when trimming the class

Comment: You posted the same function. But anyway, the problem is, I think, in the way you're calling `deleteTheseSuccess`. How are you calling it? Are you passing it as a callback?

Comment: yea, its being passed as a call back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that in your ajax callback

`dataAccess.ajaxCall(this.deleteTheseError, this.deleteTheseSuccess);`

method `this.deleteTheseSuccess` loose 'this' context (because ajax call it).

You can wrap this function by other that contains `this` as `self` variable and pass it to `dataAccess.ajaxCall`

**EDIT**

Try something like this (i write code from head so test it):

Add it to class `PrintQueue` following method

```
public deleteTheseSuccessWrapper() {
    let self = this;
    return () => { self.deleteTheseSuccess(); };
}
```

And use it in `deleteThese` method by:

```
dataAccess.ajaxCall(this.deleteTheseError, this.deleteTheseSuccessWrapper());
```

**EDIT  - version 2**

as **@estus** point out in comments: *Why is deleteTheseSuccessWrapper needed?* we can try to omit it just by using fat-arrow:

```
dataAccess.ajaxCall(this.deleteTheseError, () => { this.deleteTheseSuccess() });
```

So we have **oneliner** solution - I write above code from head but I think it should also work

Comment: can you expand on your answer a little more please

Comment: its been a long day, can you give a fuller example? In the call back method, should I do something like `let self = this` and then in the called method that has an issue call it as this or the other way round?

Comment: I’m just driving now but will try in about 20 min

Comment: Why is deleteTheseSuccessWrapper needed? This is what native `bind` already does (and more).

Answer (score 2):

`deleteTheseError` and `deleteTheseSuccess` methods are passed as callbacks. As explained in related [umbrella question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback), there are ways to bind them to proper `this` context.

It's possible to define these methods as arrow functions, but as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501) explains, a more universal way is to define them as prototype methods and bind them in class constructor:

```
constructor(callingView: string) {
    this.deleteTheseError = this.deleteTheseError.bind(this);
    this.deleteTheseSuccess = this.deleteTheseSuccess.bind(this);
    ...
}
```

Besides arrow methods, TypeScript also offers an option to use method decorators, e.g. from [`bind-decorator`](https://github.com/NoHomey/bind-decorator) package. This provides a nicer syntax for `.bind(this)`:

```
import bind from 'bind-decorator';

...
@bind
deleteTheseSuccess(data) {...}

@bind
deleteTheseError(xhr) {...}
...
```

Comment: I have just tried your approach as I am having a similar issue on other functions using the constructor to bind this and continue to face the same issue