# React and Jest: How to mock implementation of member function

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm doing some api fetching in my component. When doing unit testing, I'd like to mock the implementation of certain member functions:

```
//component.js
class Foo extends Component {
  prepareData() {
    getSthFromApi().then(getMoreFromApi).then(val=>this.setState({val}));
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.prepareData();
  }
}
//test.js
//What should this be?
Foo.prepareData = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
  this.setState({val:1});
})
const comp = shallow(<Foo />);
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't mock your member function, instead you can mock getSthFromApi function and test both componentDidmount and prepareData together.

```
import { getSthFromApi } from "some-module";
jest.mock("some-module");

// in your test
getSthFromApi.resolves(1);
// here you can expect val to be 1 in your state.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this code is that `Foo.prepareData` is static method, while `prepareData` is instance method.

Since `prepareData` is prototype method, it can be mocked on class prototype; this is [one of the reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501) why prototype methods are preferable:

```
jest
.spyOn(Foo.prototype, 'prepareData')
.mockImplementation(function () {
  this.setState({val:1});
});
```

Notice that `mockImplementation` should be provided with regular function because it doesn't need lexical `this`.

Comment: Do you mean I need to have `prepareData` as a prototype method for this code to work?

Comment: prepareData is already prototype method in the code you've posted. This `class Foo extends Component { prepareData() {...} }` is prototype method.