# difference in function call

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was trying to understand how the respective function call work when we use it in React

Suppose we have two functions like this

```
const something =  () => {
//something 
} 

function something1 () {
//something 
}
```

Till now, I have seen them being called in three different ways

like

```
{this.something}
this.something()
(() => something)
```

So my primary question is how are they different? like when being called and if there is any other way to call them (not mentioned here)?

Comment: `super` is a keyword and may not be used as identifier. Neither `{this.something}` nor `(() => something)` call the function, the first is again invalid syntax.

Comment: Are you new to JavaScript? Are you sure you should be jumping straight into react before learning the basics of the language?

Comment: `{this.something}` passes a whatever is referenced by `this.something` using the JSX javascript code escape syntax (i.e. curly braces); `this.something()` calls the function referenced by `this.something`; `(() => something)` is an arrow function which when executed returns whatever is referenced by `something`. Maybe [this tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/jackfranklin/introduction-to-ecmascript-6-part-1-arrow-functions-classes-object-literals-ajekcu7hu) will be helpful to you.

Comment: @ASDFGerte `{this.something}` is used in JSX for escaping code.

Comment: Depending on what you're trying to do, this question can be related, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881670/should-i-write-methods-as-arrow-functions-in-angulars-class .

Comment: @ASDFGerte fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.something` will not properly call a function. `this.something()` is the ideal way to call it because it's the most performant! `() => this.something()` actually triggers a re-render every time the function is called because you're creating a new function (you're literally wrapping this.something() within an empty arrow function). That being said, both are useful in different instances. When in doubt, go with `this.something()`.