# React-redux: cannot fetch the store as props using connect, Cannot read property 'props' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am trying out react and building a login form for a one page application using the same. I am using redux to store the user's information throughout the application and still cant get past through the boilerplate setup for the same.

I am almost done, but I cannot dispatch my action using the dispatch method, here is the code for my login component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

// import user actions

import { logMeIn } from "../actions/userActions"

const boxStyle = {
    width: "400px",
    margin: "40px auto",
}



export default connect((store)=>{
    return {
        user: store.user
    };
})(class loginBox extends Component {

    login() {
        let email = document.getElementById("email");
        let password = document.getElementById("password");
        email = email.value;
        password = password.value;

        return this.props.dispatch(logMeIn(email, password))
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="box" style={boxStyle}>
              <form className="form">
                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Your Email</label>
                    <input className="input" type="email" id="email" />
                </div>
                <div className="field">
                    <label className="label">Your Password</label>
                    <input className="input" type="password" id="password" />
                </div>
                <div className="level">
                    <button className="button is-dark" type="button" onClick={ this.login }>Login</button>
                    <NavLink to="/">Reset password</NavLink>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          )
        }
})
```

here, The code is compiled without any errors, and the login page is displayed, BUT when the form is submitted, following error occurs:

> ×
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined

pointing to `return this.props.dispatch(logMeIn(email, password))` line in the code.

As being new to redux, I am not able to fully understand it, however, have a look at my store:

```
    import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reducer from './reducers'
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'

const middleware = applyMiddleware(logger, thunk)

export default createStore(reducer, middleware)
```

it is simple. I am definitely missing on something here, and I do not know what it is.. please help me resolve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a special case of [this popular problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback). It isn't related to Redux. `login` method is used as a callback, and loses `this` context.

It should be either:

```
login = this.login.bind(this);

login() {...}
```

Or:

```
login = () => {...}
```

The former is preferable for [several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501).