# Sinon Spy + ReactJs property initializers syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sinon, enzyme

I'm trying to test React components with Enzyme + Sinon spies. My react code uses the property initializer syntax in my component instance:

```
class FixedButton extends React.Component {

    handleMouseOver = (e) => {
        const { fixedButtonHover = _fixedButtonHover } = this.props;
        const { backgroundColor, color } = fixedButtonHover;
        e.target.style.backgroundColor = backgroundColor;
        e.target.style.color = color;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to figure out how to spy on the handleMouseOver function, although from what I understand, since the context is bound to the instance and not a property on the prototype, I cannot spy on it.

I know the function is called and I know I can make the spies work properly by modifying my syntax to standard property style. I also know that the mounted instance of the component has the method as a property.

Is this one of those cases where the two just won't work together, or is there a trick I've failed to see?

**Edit**: here's how I tried the suggested solution, but the **spy.calledOnce** returns false as does **spy.called**:

```
test('FixedButton component methods are called as expected', t => {

    const wrapper = mount(<FixedButton />);
    const instance = wrapper.instance();
    const spy = sinon.spy(instance, 'handleMouseOver');

    const button = wrapper.find('button');
    button.simulate('mouseover');

    t.is(spy.calledOnce, true);
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prototype methods with `bind` are preferable [for several reasons including testability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881670/should-i-write-methods-as-arrow-functions-in-angulars-class), they can be spied or mocked before class instantiation. This is important for methods that are called in constructor or initial lifecycle hooks.

`handleMouseOver` is clearly event handler that is triggered after component instantiation, so it can be spied, as long as component instance is reachable via Enzyme. A component needs to be re-rendered after setting up a spy in order for `<button>` to receive a new event handler. There's [a bug with Enzyme `update()`](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1245), it needs to be worked around:

```
const instance = wrapper.instance();
const spy = sinon.spy(instance, 'handleMouseOver');
instance.forceUpdate(); // necessary for button to receive proper handler

const button = wrapper.find('button');
button.simulate('mouseover');

t.is(spy.calledOnce, true);
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, appreciate the explanation as well. I tried this syntax and while the error doesn't throw, the spy doesn't report the correct results of how many times it was called. Despite logging inside the handleMouseOver function.

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in the question how exactly you tried it.

Comment: Updated the answer, it was interesting to learn about `wrapper.update()` bug. Even if you tried `update` here, it wouldn't work. As for me, I'm using prototype methods with `bind` all the way. It's less of a concern in React but still a prototype provides extra layer of abstraction.

Comment: Thank you! Solved it. Very odd issue.