# Unable to use super to call inherited class function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, tsconfig

I am trying to call the function of the parent class from the child but the keyword `super` is throwing and error. I am using typescript, here is a snippet of the package.json from the project.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "start": "nodemon",
    "prod": "npm run build && npm run start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "dotenv": "^6.1.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.17.0",
    "@types/dotenv": "^4.0.3",
    "@types/express": "^4.16.0",
    "@types/node": "^10.12.2",
    "nodemon": "^1.18.5",
    "ts-node": "^7.0.1",
    "tslint": "^5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^3.1.6"
  }
}
```

The parent class

```
export default class baseController {

  public response = (message = "", status = 200) => (
    req: Request,
    res: Response
  ) => {
    return res.status(status).send({
      status: true, // true if success, false if faliure
      message: message, // message to display incase of error
      payload: []
    });
  };
}
```

The child class

```
import BaseController from "../baseController";

export default class UsersController extends BaseController {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  public fetchUsers = async () => {
    return super.response("testing");
  };
}
```

The code crashes on the line `return super.response("testing");` with the error `super keyword unexpected here`.

Here is my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "pretty": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "paths": {
      "*": ["node_modules/*", "src/types/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Comment: Did you notice that `BaseController` is once lowercased and once uppercased?

Comment: @CristianTraìna added the missing import statement for the base controller and tried it with all same case, still getting the issue.

Comment: I'm not so familiar with TypeScript, but with regular JS you need to have a constructor in the base class in order to call super() in the child class

Comment: @Jacob tried that too, didn't work

Comment: Try creating the functions like this:
`public async fetchUsers() {}`
instead of assigning it to a variable with all your functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This case is one of several reasons why prototype methods may be preferred over arrow class fields (instance methods), as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45882417/3731501).

There are several problems here.

One problem is that there's no `super.response`. `super` refers to parent class prototype, while `response` is instance method.

Another problem is that the target is ES6. `async` is transpiled to generators, and `super` is not transpiled, this results in incorrect code:

```
fetchUsers.a = () => __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { return super.response("testing") });
```

Only arrow functions can get `super` from parent scope, `super` is not allowed inside non-arrow functions. Since there are no arrow generators, `super` use is invalid inside a generator. While TypeScript is able to handle `super` properly in `async` *prototype* methods:

```
fetchUsers() {
    const _super = name => super[name];
    return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function* () { _super.response("testing").call(this); });
}
```

Yet another problem is that referring to `super` in a class that doesn't override `response` is semantic mistake. Child class already inherits `response`. It can be used as `this` method.

It should be:

```
export default class baseController {
  public response(message = "", status = 200) (...) { ... }
}

export default class UsersController extends BaseController {
  public async fetchUsers() {
    return this.response("testing");
  };
}
```

If `fetchUsers` is expected to be used as a callback (this is the only good use for arrow methods), it should be bound to `this` context in constructor:

```
  public fetchUsers = this.fetchUsers.bind(this);

  public async fetchUsers() {
    return this.response("testing");
  };
```

Where `fetchUsers` class field is sugar syntax for constructor body.

Comment: How do you use `fetchUsers`? If you use it as a callback then the last paragraph obviously applies. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback.

Comment: yeah I forgot to bind the function.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is with how you're creating the class's functions.
It should be like this:

```
export class baseController {

    public response(message = "", status = 200) { 

    }
}


export class UsersController extends baseController {

  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  public async fetchUsers() {
    return super.response("testing");
  };
}
```