# How to bind a function of a React component to "this" without a constructor?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

As many know, `this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this)` can be used in React class components. However, sometimes it's burdensome to create classes for very simple components. So, how can I bind a function to `this` without creating a class?

Comment: you can use es6 `arrow function`. No need to bind this for that

Comment: if you have a simple component how/why are you referencing `this` inside the component? pure functional components are generally for presentation and should have any values they need passed as props, whats the requirement to access `this`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use arrow function [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but I suggest you elaborate a little bit with an example, which would add some more value for future readers stumbling upon this question.

Answer (score 2):

`this` makes sense in class component because it refers to component instance. It doesn't make sense in functional component because it is either `undefined` or a global, depending on the environment and how a function was declared.

As for class components, explicit constructor can be omitted if it's not needed, [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields) can be used to assign instance properties, including bound methods:

```
class Foo extends Component {
  foo = this.foo.bind(this);

  foo() { ... }
  ...
}
```

Which is syntactic sugar for:

```
class Foo extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.foo = this.foo.bind(this);
  }

  foo() { ... }
  ...
}
```

Bound prototype methods have [several benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45881670/should-i-write-methods-as-arrow-functions-in-angulars-class/45882417#45882417) over instance arrow methods.

Answer (score 1):

In React 16.8, you can use [hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-overview.html) for stateful components, essentially allowing you to write everything as a function and eliminating the need to use classes and all the caveats that come with them (`this`, `.bind()` etc).

#### Usage example

Here's an example of using the [`useState()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) and the [`useEffect()` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) inside a function, along with an arrow function, which is already bound to the component's context:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function LimitedTextarea({ rows, cols, value, limit }) {
  const [content, setContent] = useState(value);

  const setFormattedContent = text => {
    text.length > limit ? setContent(text.slice(0, limit)) : setContent(text);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setFormattedContent(content);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        rows={rows}
        cols={cols}
        onChange={event => setFormattedContent(event.target.value)}
        value={content}
      />
      <p>
        {content.length}/{limit}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

#### Short explanation

- You use `useState()` to create a state variable `content` and a method to update that variable, `setContent()`.
- You create an arrow function `setFormattedContent` to update the `content` state variable via the `setContent` method, which is already bound to context.
- You use `useEffect()` to call `setFormattedContent` on the value of the `content` state variable.
- Finally, you return whatever you would have in your `render()` method in a class component.

Answer (score 0):

Yes arrow function is the solution.

Bind with this,

```
this.someFunction = this.someFunction.bind(this)
```

Using arrow function,

```
someFunction = () => {
   // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to bind "this" If you use arrow function. It has simple and cleaner syntax.

```
someFuncton = () => {
    // whatever write here...
}
```