# Angular: Cyclic Dependency

Tags: angular, validation, angular-custom-validators

Why is `currentdate` in `this.currentdate.getTime()` coming back as undefined?

```
newlisting = this.formBuilder.group({
    availabledate: new FormGroup({
      xyz: new FormControl()
    },[this.mainservice.getcurrenttime.bind(this)])
})
```

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MainService {

  constructor(){}
 
  currentdate: Date = new Date();

  getcurrenttime(control: FormGroup){

    console.log(this.currentdate.getTime())  <~~ Generates Error!!!

    if(condition){
      return {date: true};
    }
    return null;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like `this.mainservice.getcurrenttime.bind(this)`, it creates a bound function.

Due to the above created bound function, in your case within `getcurrenttime()` method `this` would be referred to as `YourComponent` instance.

Since the component doesn't have any property named `currentdate` declared, `this.currentdate` will result in `undefined` and trying to read `getTime()` on it will result in an error.

---

###### Below are few of the alternatives you can use:

1. Bind it to the `mainservice` instance

```ts
this.mainservice.getcurrenttime.bind(this.mainservice)
```

2. Return a ValidatorFn from `getcurrenttime` as below, so that you don't lose the `this` context. *(I would recommend this approach)*

```ts
// Within MainService
getcurrenttime(): ValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl) => {
    console.log(this.currentdate.getTime());
    // Your logic
    return null;
  }
}

// Within YourComponent
this.mainservice.getcurrenttime()
```

3. Define `getcurrenttime` as an arrow function and then you don't need to use `bind`.

```ts
// Within MainService
getcurrenttime = (control: AbstractControl) => {
  console.log(this.currentdate.getTime());
  // Your logic
  return null;
}

// Within YourComponent
this.mainservice.getcurrenttime  // No need to use .bind(...)
```

[Should I write methods as arrow functions in Angular class](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45881670/9471852)

Comment: First thank-you, and interesting stuff. In example 1 (which worked), how does this work, wouldn't changing `this` to `this.mainservice` instead send the entire mainservice over to the function? Even with it working, I am not understanding how bind actually works maybe. I will try the other two options later today and report back any questions.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2236747/9471852 this post consists of multiple answers, which you might find helpful in understanding how `bind` works.

Answer (score 0):

set validate without .bind()

```
newlisting = this.formBuilder.group({
    availabledate: new FormGroup({
      XYZ: new FormControl()
    },[this.mainservice.getcurrenttime()])
})
```

I think you can define that currentDate variable inside the method.

```
 const currentdate: Date = new Date();
```

and I think you should return something like this.

```
getCurrentTime(): ValidatorFn {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const currentDate: Date = new Date();

      const year = formGroup.get('year').value;
      const month = formGroup.get('month').value;
      const day = formGroup.get('day').value;

      const selectedDate = new Date(year, month, day, 0, 0, 0, 0);

      if (selectedDate === currentDate) {
        formGroup.setErrors({ any_error: true }); // on your form group
        return null;
      } else return null;
    };
  }
```