# Value of "THIS" in handler functions in React without binding the function

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

```
  export default class DetailsPage extends React.PureComponent {
constructor() {
    super();
     this.state = {
        data: '',
        isModalOpen: false,
    };

  **//this.openModal = this.openModal.bind(this);**
    }
openModal() {
      console.log(this, "this in Handler");
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
}

closeModal() {
    this.setState({ isModalOpen: false });
}
```

**Case 1 (No Binding in click Handler )**

```
    render() {

    return (

       (<div className="left">

                <button className="btn btn btn-primary" type="button" 
                 onClick={this.openModal}>Edit</button>
         </div>
       );
     )
  }
}
```

**Case 2 (Binding with this)**

```
    render() {

    return (

       (<div className="left">

                <button className="btn btn btn-primary" type="button" 
                 onClick={this.openModal.bind(this)}>Edit</button>
         </div>
       );
     )
  }
}
```

In my click Handler `openModal()` I have written `console.log(this)`

**In Case 1** : the value of "THIS" comes out to be `NULL` in react .

**In Case 2** : the value of "THIS" comes out to be that of component (that is perfectly okay).

**My doubts:**

1. why does "THIS "comes out to be `NULL` in the first case.
2. **What is the use of `super()` in constructor** ? I have read about it and got to know what happens if we remove the `super()` and difference between super() & super(props). But I want to know the functionality that happens in the background when we call `super()`.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been asked and answered in a [variety of ways](https://www.sitepoint.com/bind-javascripts-this-keyword-react/) -- but my favorite is probably the ES2015 arrow function syntax:

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    someMethod = () => {
        // "this" is bound automatically!
        console.log(this, "this in Handler");
        this.setState({ isModalOpen: true });
    }
}
```

As a caveat, there are [pros and cons](https://reactarmory.com/answers/when-to-use-arrow-functions) to always doing this -- the most often-quoted being "performance". Twitter wars have been fought over this, but IMO Ryan Florence (co-author of React Router) [said it best](https://twitter.com/ryanflorence/status/905584680451268608).

Comment: Generally prototype method that was bound with `bind` has [more benefits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501) than an arrow.

Comment: While arrow functions play a crucial part in this solution, you are actually using an experimental feature: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields . Also, the performance debate you mention is about *inline* event handlers, i.e. functions defined in the render method. Yours is create different at construction time.