# Are there any functional differences between using fat arrow syntax or not for ES6 class methods and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

Here are two examples of writing an ES6 class method:

The first uses non-fat arrow, or concise method syntax--whatever it is correctly called:

```
class Test extends Component {
  handleClick() {
    return 'clicked'
  }
}
```

The second uses fat arrow syntax:

```
class Test2 extends Component {
  handleClick = () => {
    return 'clicked'
  }
}
```

Should I always prefer to write using fat arrow syntax?

One thing I notice is you could use implicit return which could shorten code.

In most examples I see of people writing `constructor()` and `render()` methods in **React**, they do **not** use fat arrow syntax for those, but they do for all other class methods.

Why is this?

I am guessing the answer will have something to do with the `this` keyword since it is fairly intrinsic to classes and the context-preserving nature of fat arrows, but how does this relate to React and fat arrow syntax on class methods? The only case I can think of is that you might be able to avoid binding in the constructor for some cases depending how the class method is called later.

I would appreciate a scientific answer or a list of cases where a distinction is important.

Comment: It should be noted that methods such as `render`, `constructor`, and lifecycle hooks are internally called by React with the component as the `this` context, essentially meaning no binding is needed. The same is not true for event handlers, which need explicitly binding to the component.

Comment: "two examples of writing an ES6 class method" The second example isn't even ES6, it's a syntax extension that Babel supports.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600967/can-i-use-arrow-function-in-constructor-of-a-react-component

Comment: Suggested reading https://blog.andrewray.me/react-es6-autobinding-and-createclass/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the render function below

```
render() {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick} />
}
```

When `handleClick` is defined as an arrow function, the function is executed when the click event is fired. Otherwise it's run at the same time as `render`.

> Should I always prefer to write using fat arrow syntax?

It depends on how/from where you need to call your function. For event handlers, arrow functions are convenient because as you state the component's `this` is accessible and you also need to pass in the function as opposed to its output.

If you don't need to access the component's `this` or pass your function, then an arrow function is not necessary.

Comment: I like the information about execution time, but can you really consider an arrow function's context to be 'bound'? They just don't have context.

Comment: @Andrew What I meant is that `.bind(this)` is automatically done for you when using arrow functions.

Comment: That's not true. Arrow functions intrinsically have no context. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: @FuzzyTree Andrew is right; the fact is once arrow function class properties are transpiled, they become properties assigned in the *constructor* like so: `foo = () => {...}` becomes `constructor() { this.foo = () => {...} }` where arrow functions don't bind this so they take `this` of the surrounding scope which is the class.

Answer (score 1):

Fat arrow functions are context agnostic. This means that places that normally put function out of context will stay in the proper context. The most common (possibly only?) use case of this in React is for event handlers.

These are all functionally equivalent. All commonplaces:

```
// 1
handleClick() {
  this.setState({clicked: true})
}

<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>

//2
constructor() {
  super()
  this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
}
handleClick() {
  this.setState({clicked: true})
}

<button onClick={this.handleClick}/>

//3
handleClick() {
  this.setState({clicked: true})
}

<button onClick={() => this.handleClick()}/>

//4
handleClick = () => {
  this.setState({clicked: true})
}

<button onClick={this.handleClick}/>
```

Boils down to preference. The only one that you could be 'pegged' for is `<button onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}/>`, for performance issues.