# es6 arrow function in class property

Tags: reactjs, class, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I bundle the codes with `./node_modules/.bin/webpack -d`. I didn't compile ES6 to ES5 except this `class fields proposal`.

It give this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.fetchTestExecutions is not a function

Here's the codes:

```
import React from 'react'
import Config from 'Config'

class HomePage extends React.Component {

  state = {
    executions: this.fetchTestExecutions()
  }

  fetchTestExecutions = () => {
    const host = Config.host
    return fetch(`${host}/execution/index`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({executions: json})
      })
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        { this.state.executions.map(x => <div>x.from</div>) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default HomePage
```

Here's the webpack.config.js:

```
var webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/App.jsx',
  output: {
    filename: './../public/bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        query: {
          plugins: ['transform-class-properties'],
          presets: ['react'],
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    'Config': JSON.stringify({host: "http://127.0.0.1:3000"})
  }
}
```

What's wrong?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class fields (which are currently stage 2 proposal) are assigned on class instantiation. The original code is equal to this ES6 code:

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = {
      executions: this.fetchTestExecutions()
    };

    this.fetchTestExecutions = () => { /*...*/ };
  }
  ...
}
```

As it appears, the order matters, and `fetchTestExecutions` is undefined at the moment when it's being called.

In order to make it work, `fetchTestExecutions` class field should be defined before `state`.

Unless `fetchTestExecutions` is used as a callback (and it's not), it should definitely be prototype method (already suggested in another answer):

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    executions: this.fetchTestExecutions()
  }

  fetchTestExecutions() { /*...*/ }
  ...
}
```

This eliminates the problem and results in more efficient code. See also [this explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501) on what are the practical differences between arrow (instance) and prototype methods.

Answer (score 3):

Setting a method (specially an api call) as a state property is not a good pattern. Instead, prefer calling the api first in a lifecycle event and then set state later.

```
class HomePage extends React.Component {
  state = {
    executions: []
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const host = Config.host

    fetch(`${host}/execution/index`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({ executions: json }))
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        { this.state.executions.map(x => <div>x.from</div>) }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: He's not setting the method, he's setting the promise returned from that method. However, it's definitely a very bad pattern.

Comment: Yes, sure. It was just a mean to explain the bad pattern :)

Comment: Hi @mersocarlin, thanks for the advise on setting state. what if I got another `randomString = () => "a string"`, and `state = { executions: this.randomString()}`. It still give the same error. `state` is a class variable? `this.randomString()` is instance method?

Comment: @mCY `state` is an object [link to docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html). And I wouldn't use method (as `randomString` for example) to set its initial properties. `this.randomString()` is an instance method if you defined it inside your component (which allows you to call `this.randomString()`) from anywhere within the component.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change your function like this

```
fetchTestExecutions(){
const host = Config.host
return fetch(`${host}/execution/index`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    this.setState({executions: json})
  })
}
```