# Multiple bind this (shorten code)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, this, bind

Multiple >4 (around 10) function with bind this in the constructor.
Is there a way to shorten the code?

```
constructor(props: SignupProps) {
    super(props);
    this._setDirty = this._setDirty.bind(this);
    this._handleUserInput = this._handleUserInput.bind(this);
    this._A = this._A.bind(this);
    this._B = this._B.bind(this);
}
```

I tried the following but couldn't.

```
 [this._setDirty, _this.handleUserInput, this._A, this._B].bind(this);
```

Comment: Read http://egorsmirnov.me/2015/08/16/react-and-es6-part3.html (*in particular method 4*)

Comment: Could you maybe use arrow function properties?

Comment: Yes can use arrow function in es6

Answer (score 1):

You need to for-loop the methods and call `.bind` per each iteration to make your approach work. For example:

```
const methods = ['_setDirty', '_a', '_b', ...];
methods.forEach(method => this[method] = this[method].bind(this));
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods should be assigned with a loop (another answer already mentions that):

```
for (const prop of ['_setDirty', /* ... */])
  this[prop] = this[prop].bind(this);
```

Using arrows instead of prototype methods allows to skip `bind` but this is the only benefit, [bound prototype methods are generally preferable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501) because of their flexibility.

Since React is in use, it's safe to assume that a transpiler is used as well, so the project is not limited to ES6.

Decorators can be conveniently used in ES.Next code to bind methods, e.g. `bind-decorator`:

```
import bind from 'bind-decorator';

...
constructor(props: SignupProps) {
    super(props);
}

@bind
_setDirty() {...}
...
```