# React onChange functions with ES6 arrows or not

Tags: reactjs, forms, ecmascript-6, dom-events, arrow-functions

When handling an `onChange` event, this one works:

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onChange}
```

Not this one, that executes instantaneously the function:

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onChange()}
```

Not this other one, doesn't execute:

```
<input type="file" onChange={() => this.onChange}
```

But this one does:

```
<input type="file" onChange={() => this.onChange()}
```

But, while the first one automatically sends the *event* object, the second one needs to explicitly send it:

```
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
onChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
}
```

Why is that? and when should we use one or the another?

Comment: Try adding `console.log(this)` to see the difference between the two working approaches

Comment: I haven't mentioned but the binding is included: this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this)

Comment: In that case, an additional arrow function wrapper is completely superfluous and should not be used.

Comment: See also regarding `bind`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43600967/can-i-use-arrow-function-in-constructor-of-a-react-component . This applies to React to lesser extent than to generic OOP, but `bind` is preferable in general.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With `onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}`, you are essentially creating a new function that calls **this.onChange** method during each render.

With `onChange={this.onChange}`, you are directly accessing **this.onChange** method. This method is only defined once and is used multiple times. Basically, you are avoiding creating a new function with a new render thus giving the application a slight performance enhancement

Comment: Thanks for both answers :)
This one is the one clearer to me

Answer (score 9):

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onChange}
```

This works because `onChange` prop is a function, then you are passing a function reference to it, so it works. And `<input>` is responsible for passing event parameter to it.

---

```
<input type="file" onChange={this.onChange()}
```

This doesn't work because you are assigning to `onChange` prop the result value of the onChange function. (But depending of your function, it could work)

---

```
<input type="file" onChange={() => this.onChange}
```

This also doesn't work because you are creating a new function, and inside it, you are using the reference to a function `this.onChange` you are not executing it  (with parentheses).

---

```
<input type="file" onChange={() => this.onChange()}
```

This executes the function (you are calling `this.onChange()`) inside your anonymous function, but you are not passing parameters to it, so how do you expect to get event info inside `this.onChange` function?

---

```
<input type="file" onChange={(e) => this.onChange(e)}
onChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.files[0])
}
```

This resolve my previous point, now in your anonymous function you are getting event info `e`, and you are passing it to your `onChange` function. Then it works.