# How to mock a react component's event when fat arrow function is used as event handler?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-dom

i want to mock handleClick event of my TodoForm component.

TodoForm.jsx

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

    export class TodoForm extends Component {

        handleClick = () => {
            console.log("handle click is called");
        }

        render() {
            return (
                <div>
                    <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Clik</button>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
```

in TodoForm.test.js

```
import React from 'react'
import { mount, shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { TodoForm } from "../TodoForm";


it("must call the mock function when button is clicked", () => {
    const mocked = jest.fn();
    const wrapper = mount(<TodoForm />);

    wrapper.instance().handleClick = mocked;
    wrapper.update();

    wrapper.find("button").simulate("click");
    expect(mocked).toHaveBeenCalled();


})
```

the test fails with "Expected mock function to have been called, but it was not called."

instead of calling the mock function it calls the real implementation.

I am using 
create-react-app,

react:16.6.3,
 enzyme: 3.8.0,
enzyme-adapter-react-16 :1.7.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue with Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme/issues/1245). `update()` doesn't cause a re-render. This results in triggering original `handleClick`, because `render` function was called before mocking the method.

A workaround is to use `wrapper.instance().forceUpdate()` instead of `wrapper.update()`.

Testability is [one of several reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43601993/3731501) to prefer bound prototype methods over arrow instance methods.