# React-Time-Range Only Shows Default Start Time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I've created a form using the **React-Time-Range** component for taking down banquet room reservations.  For some reason, the start time being recorded always defaults to the `moment()` value I have listed in state.

Can you take a look at my code below to help determine why it does not change, even when a user selects a different value?

The component:

```
import moment from 'moment';
import TimeRange from 'react-time-range';

class Navbar extends Component {
 constructor(props){
 super(props)
 this.state = {
  startTime: moment(),
  endTime: moment()
}
}

returnFunctionStart = event => {
    this.setState({ startTime: event.startTime })
    };

  returnFunctionEnd = event => {
    this.setState({ endTime: event.endTime })
    };

render () {
return (
    <TimeRange
        onStartTimeChange={this.returnFunctionStart.bind(this)}
        onEndTimeChange={this.returnFunctionEnd}
        startMoment={this.state.startTime}
        endMoment={this.state.endTime}
    />
);
}
```

It is working fine for end time. Thanks.

Comment: so when changing the start time it is not reflecting is that the issue ?

Comment: Just tested out, it works as expected. Where do you face issues? Thanks!

Comment: DILEEP -- exactly right...it reflects in the UI, but when I try to retrieve the value for a sendgrid email, the default value appears.  very strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code works fine, if you are using latest version of react you can clean up some code as shown below

You can avoid

1. Binding [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192682/react-js-es6-avoid-binding-this-to-every-method)
2. Constructor, since babel takes care of it [read more here](https://hackernoon.com/the-constructor-is-dead-long-live-the-constructor-c10871bea599)

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

import moment from "moment";
import TimeRange from "react-time-range";

class Navbar extends Component {
  state = {
    startTime: moment(),
    endTime: moment()
  };

  returnFunctionStart = event => {
    this.setState({
      startTime: event.startTime
    });
  };

  returnFunctionEnd = event => {
    this.setState({
      endTime: event.endTime
    });
  };

  render() {
    return ( <
      TimeRange onStartTimeChange = {
        this.returnFunctionStart
      }
      onEndTimeChange = {
        this.returnFunctionEnd
      }
      startMoment = {
        this.state.startTime
      }
      endMoment = {
        this.state.endTime
      }
      />
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render( < Navbar / > , rootElement);
```

Working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/59579577-so-react-time-range-only-shows-default-start-time-k8gk4)