# Creating ES6 Class definitions with constructor keyword and this

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got the following working JavaScript class.I'm hoping there is an ES6 way of doing it without having to use the `constructor` keyword and also minimize the use of `this`. I've tried statements like

`state = {hasError: false}`

and that works for just hasError, but can't figure out how to handle the function bind. I'm hoping not to have to do that like I don't have to use this to access state with the new syntax.

```js
export default class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
    this.updateHasErrorsToFalse = this.updateHasErrorsToFalse.bind(this);
  }

  updateHasErrorsToFalse() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      hasError: false,
    }));
  }

  //state = { hasError: false, error: null,  };

  static getDerivedStateFromError(error) {
    return {
      hasError: true,
      error: error.message
    };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error, errorInfo) {
    // You can also log the error to an error reporting service
    console.log(error, errorInfo);
  }

  updateHasErrorsToFalse() {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      hasError: false,
    }));
  }

  render() {
    function addExtraProps(Component, extraProps) {
      return <Component.type {...Component.props} {...extraProps} />;
    }

    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return addExtraProps(this.props.fallback, {
        error: this.state.error,
        resetError: this.updateHasErrorsToFalse,
      });
    }
    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

Comment: This question has been answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192682/react-js-es6-avoid-binding-this-to-every-method

Comment: NB: `constructor` is not a keyword.

Comment: @trincot what is "constructor"?

Comment: Whatever you want it to be, but if you use it as a method name in a `class` syntax, it will serve as the constructor.

Comment: "*I'm hoping there is an ES6 way of doing it without having to use the `constructor` keyword and also minimize the use of `this`*" - not sure what you think is wrong with using constructors and the `this` keyword?

Comment: is constructor a reserved word? I'm confused

Comment: "*I can't figure out how to handle the function bind*" - well in exactly the same way as you handled `state`, just convert it into a class field: `updateHasErrorsToFalse = this.updateHasErrorsToFalse.bind(this);`.

Comment: No, [`constructor` is not a reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#keywords)

Comment: @berg, I find statements like `this.updateHasErrorsToFalse = this.updateHasErrorsToFalse.bind(this);` confusing to write and read

Answer (score 2):

By doing the following, you bind `this` to `function` manually.

```
this.updateHasErrorsToFalse = this.updateHasErrorsToFalse.bind(this);
```

Instead of that, you can use the arrow function notation which has the lexical binding of `this`.

```
  updateHasErrorsToFalse = () => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      hasError: false,
    }));
  }
```

And you can remove `constructor` and have `state` instance as below.

Instead of

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { hasError: false };
    this.updateHasErrorsToFalse = this.updateHasErrorsToFalse.bind(this);
  }
```

Just keep following in the class level

```
state = { hasError: false };
```

Comment: @Peter Kellner, check this out !!

Comment: When I do `state = { hasError: false };` I get a lint error "unexpected token"

Comment: @Peter Kellner, Now I guess it's related to the configuration of linting. If you fix it all good to go!

Comment: @PeterKellner The arrow function is your best bet. I also don't think there's  problem with having the state initialized in your constructor.