# Making keyboard behave to a text area like <TextInput>

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I have a screen is this kind of a screen. (Very similar to compose email in Gmail app)

```
<View>
    <View>
        Content X
    </View>
    <View>
        Content Y
    </View>
    <ScrollView>
        <TextInput/> {/*Text Area like TextInput*/}
    </ScrollView>
</View>
```

The issue what i'm facing is, when editing, the cursor manages to go behind the keyboard.  doesn't really help in this scenario.

Similar behaviour I have noticed in the Gmail app

[This is the kind of screen i'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0tcJe.png)

[This is the kind of behaviour i'm trying to replicate. The cursor in the gmail app never ends up behind the keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ikjg.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would just use this component https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

Comment: Works quite excellent on textinput. But doesn't work if the textinput in question already has content behind keyboard.

Comment: in that case I think this guys answer is more like what you need (focus + offset) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546742/react-native-how-to-move-screen-up-on-textinput

Comment: I think that answer more or less revolves around multiple single lined textInput. Not exactly with this case.