# move the view up when keyboard as shown in react-native

Tags: react-native

hai i am trying to move the view up when keyboard as shown using react-native,I followed the @sherlock's comment in ([How to auto-slide the window out from behind keyboard when TextInput has focus?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313244/how-to-auto-slide-the-window-out-from-behind-keyboard-when-textinput-has-focus?answertab=active#tab-top).But) i got an error like this[image]

I don't know how to resolve this error, can any one help me how to resolve this, any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There's a great discussion about this in the react-native github issues
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3195#issuecomment-147427391

I'd start there, but here are a couple more links you may find useful, one of which is mentioned already in the article you referenced...

- [[React Tips] Responding to the keyboard with React Native](https://medium.com/man-moon/writing-modern-react-native-ui-e317ff956f02)
- [Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer](https://github.com/Andr3wHur5t/react-native-keyboard-spacer)

Answer (score 0):

In my library "react-native-form-generator" (https://github.com/MichaelCereda/react-native-form-generator) i did the following.

I created a Keyboard Aware scroll view (partially modified from https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3195#issuecomment-146518331)

the following it's just an excerpt

```
export class KeyboardAwareScrollView extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      keyboardSpace: 0,
    }
    this.updateKeyboardSpace = this.updateKeyboardSpace.bind(this)
    this.resetKeyboardSpace = this.resetKeyboardSpace.bind(this)
  }


  updateKeyboardSpace (frames) {

    let coordinatesHeight = frames.endCoordinates.height;
    const keyboardSpace = (this.props.viewIsInsideTabBar) ? coordinatesHeight - 49 : coordinatesHeight
    this.setState({
      keyboardSpace: keyboardSpace,
    })

  }

  resetKeyboardSpace () {
    this.setState({
      keyboardSpace: 0,
    })
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    // Keyboard events
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this.updateKeyboardSpace)
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this.resetKeyboardSpace)
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('keyboardWillShow')
    DeviceEventEmitter.removeAllListeners('keyboardWillHide')
  }

  scrollToFocusedInput (event, reactNode, extraHeight = 69) {
    const scrollView = this.refs.keyboardScrollView.getScrollResponder();
    setTimeout(() => {
      scrollView.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
        reactNode, extraHeight, true
      )
    }, 220)
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <ScrollView
        ref='keyboardScrollView'
        keyboardDismissMode='interactive'
        contentInset={{bottom: this.state.keyboardSpace}}
        showsVerticalScrollIndicator={true}
        style={this.props.style}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  }
```

Then i use it like any other scrollview

```
import { KeyboardAwareScrollView } from 'react-native-form-generator'
...
handleFormFocus(event, reactNode){
   this.refs.scroll.scrollToFocusedInput(event, reactNode)
}
...
  <KeyboardAwareScrollView ref='scroll'>
    <Form ref='registrationForm'
      onFocus={this.handleFormFocus.bind(this)}
      onChange={this.handleFormChange.bind(this)}
      label="Personal Information">
      ........
    </Form>
</KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

on change my component (Form) will call scrollToFocusedInput in KeyboardAwareScrollView (using the ref).

i suggest to check the code of my library (see the link on top), or simply use it (everything it's already tested and working).

If you have further questions just comment