# on ios when TextInput focused it's behind keyboard (react-native)

Tags: ios, react-native, mobile-development

I am using listView with TextInputs, on ios when TextInput focused it's behind keyboard. How to fix it?

Sample code: http://rnplay.org/apps/8baZSA

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `<ScrollView>` instead of `<View>` in order to use this method.

The key method is `scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(refToElement, scrollHeight, preventNegativeOffset)` (sounds cool, right ;))

I have:

```
<TextInput ref='ccName' onFocus={(() => this.onFieldFocus('ccName'))} />
```

where function looks like:

```
onFieldFocus(fieldName) {
  this.setTimeout(() => {
    let scrollResponder = this.refs.scrollView.getScrollResponder()
    scrollResponder.scrollResponderScrollNativeHandleToKeyboard(
      React.findNodeHandle(this.refs[fieldName]), 200, true
    )
  }, 125) 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as you can see in my example I use ListView.

Comment: Wrap the ListView inside ScrollView then?

Comment: Can you share example on rnplay.org , please?

Answer (score 0):

Seems [this thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/415) is what you're looking for.

TL;DR: [see this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313244/how-to-auto-slide-the-window-out-from-behind-keyboard-when-textinput-has-focus)

Comment: `listView.getScrollResponder().scrollTo();` doesn't work? (listView is a ref to the ListView element you have)

Comment: Can you share an easy example in rnplay.org, please?

Comment: I'd like to, but seems your example crashes on rnplay.