# React Native ListView/ScrollView not work on FIRST click after pull down or srcoll

Tags: listview, react-native, click, scrollview, react-native-navigation

It seems similar with [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36476542/react-native-requires-two-taps-to-change-input-focus-when-within-scrollview)
But it not happens on TextInput. Here is my code:

```
renderRow (rowData, sectionId, rowId) {
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => {
  //be Clicked
})}>
  <View style={styles.root}>
    <Image style={styles.img} source={defaultAvatar} />
    <View style={styles.detail}>
      <Text allowFontScaling={false} numberOfLines={1} style={styles.name}>{nickName}</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
}

render () {
return
    <ListView
      style={[{padding: 10, backgroundColor: grayBgColor, width: screenWidth}, this.props.style]}
      dataSource={this.state.ds}
      renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)}
      renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionHeader}
      renderHeader={this.renderHeader}
    />
}
```

2 ways to reproduce this bug(on iOS, RN version is 0.42):

1. pull down (no refresh action), then click any row. I did not get any response
2. let the scroll area do inertia motion. when it stoped just click any row, no response.

Maybe it has some relation ship with ScrollView. Anyone can help me to reslove this bug?

Comment: first click not work but once more is OK

Comment: more info...we found that it caused by module: react-native-navigation. Still working to find out why

Comment: any solution? We're having this issue with pull-to-refresh as well on React Native 0.55 with react-navigation 1.5