# How to get textInputs into focus in react-native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im new to react-native and may be the question Im asking can be very noob. 
But Im not able to find any reference for it somehow.

[image]

There are 6 text inputs in the picture, but we can merely see 4 when keyboard appears, so how can we get 5th text input into visible area when keyboard is still there ?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want to scroll the input when clicked so it is visible when the keyboard is opened. There is a nice library to handle this easily.

https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view

```js
const Screen = React.createClass({

  _scrollToInput(event) {
    this.refs.scrollview.scrollToFocusedInput(event, event.nativeEvent.target);
  },

  render() {
    return (
      <KeyboardAwareScrollView ref="scrollview">
        <View>
          <TextInput onFocus={this._scrollToInput}/>
        </View>
      </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
    );
  },
});
```

Comment: With your help I was able to find this , 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313244/how-to-auto-slide-the-window-out-from-behind-keyboard-when-textinput-has-focus

Very useful.