# get coordinates when a textinput in react-native is in focus

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Can we get the x,y coordinates of TextInput when it is focused , i mean when the keyboard is shown ?

Extending my above question, my actual question is how can we animate a TextInput into user visible area when that TextInput is in focus. What are the good approaches for it ?

I have seen some approaches like [this](https://github.com/jrans/react-native-smart-scroll-view/blob/master/complexFormExample.js) but it shrinks the TextInput. 
Can anyone help me out there ?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29313244/how-to-auto-slide-the-window-out-from-behind-keyboard-when-textinput-has-focus) might help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have bookmarked a few helpful articles and components related to this that I can share with you. The first one is a ready to use component, while the other three answer the question of how.

- https://github.com/jrans/react-native-smart-scroll-view#form
- https://medium.com/man-moon/writing-modern-react-native-ui-e317ff956f02
- http://www.reactnative.com/keyboard-events-for-react-native/
- https://shift.infinite.red/avoiding-the-keyboard-in-react-native-56d05b9a1e81#.3pgghjm7v

Comment: BTW which you will prefer among the list ? @Chris

Comment: Been a while since I looked at any of them, but I'd start with the component, either use it whole sale or peek under the hood for implementation insight. If that didn't work, review the articles for alternative approaches